# HTTPS using Jersey Client

Tags: java, jersey

How do I send GET requests using the Jersey Client API to a server which runs on the HTTPS protocol. Is there any sample code that I can use ?

Comment: shall you provide code for create rest jersey with https ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Construct your client as such

```
HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
ctx.init(null, myTrustManager, null);
config.getProperties().put(HTTPSProperties.PROPERTY_HTTPS_PROPERTIES, new HTTPSProperties(hostnameVerifier, ctx));
Client client = Client.create(config);
```

Ripped from this blog post with more details: http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/consuming_restful_web_services_with

For information on setting up your certs, see this nicely answered SO question: [Using HTTPS with REST in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757295/using-https-with-rest-in-java)

Comment: Do you have the code from that blog posting?  It doesn't appear to be available for download anymore.  :(

Comment: Could you please tell me what Hostnames verifier and myTrustManager should be? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434309/accessing-secure-restful-web-services-using-jersey-client

Comment: That code will never run, since it's missing the hostnameVerifier. Please complete the example, instead of linking outside which may break at any time.

Answer (score 24):

HTTPS using Jersey client has two different version if you are using java 6 ,7 and 8
then

```
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
```

If using java 8 then

```
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1");
```

Please find working code

POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>WebserviceJersey2Spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebserviceJersey2Spring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.16</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Jersey -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            </dependency>



        <!-- Jersey + Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>
                    jersey-container-servlet-core
                </artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hk2</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

JAVA CLASS

```
package com.example.client;




import org.glassfish.jersey.client.authentication.HttpAuthenticationFeature;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class JerseyClientGet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String username = "username";
            String password = "p@ssword";
        String input = "{\"userId\":\"12345\",\"name \":\"Viquar\",\"surname\":\"Khan\",\"Email\":\"Vaquar.khan@gmail.com\"}";
        try {
        //SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");//Java 6
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");//Java 8
        System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1");//Java 8


        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = { new InsecureTrustManager() };
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new InsecureHostnameVerifier();

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sc).hostnameVerifier(allHostsValid).build();

        HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.universalBuilder()
                    .credentialsForBasic(username, password).credentials(username, password).build();


            client.register(feature);
                    //PUT request, if need uncomment it 
                    //final Response response = client
                    //.target("https://localhost:7002/VaquarKhanWeb/employee/api/v1/informations")
                    //.request().put(Entity.entity(input, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), Response.class);
            //GET Request
            final Response response = client
                    .target("https://localhost:7002/VaquarKhanWeb/employee/api/v1/informations")
                    .request().get();




            if (response.getStatus() != HttpStatus.OK.value()) { throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + response.getStatus()); }
            String output = response.readEntity(String.class);
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            System.out.println(output);
            client.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

HELPER CLASS

```
package com.example.client;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;

public class InsecureHostnameVerifier implements HostnameVerifier {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Helper class

```
package com.example.client;

import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class InsecureTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType) throws CertificateException {
        // Everyone is trusted!
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType) throws CertificateException {
        // Everyone is trusted!
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new X509Certificate[0];
    }
}
```

Once you start running application will get Certificate error ,download certificate from browser and add into

```
C:\java-8\jdk1_8_0\jre\lib\security
```

Add into cacerts , you will get details in following links.

Few useful link to understand error

- http://www.9threes.com/2015/01/restful-java-client-with-jersey-client.html

  [Java: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908948/java-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find)

  http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/ssl/pkix_path_building_failed.html

  [Java Keytool error after importing certificate , "keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException & Access Denied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321211/java-keytool-error-after-importing-certificate-keytool-error-java-io-filenot)

I have tested following code for get and post method with SSL and basic Authentication here you can skip SSL Certificate , you can directly copy three class and add jar into java project and run.

```
package com.rest.client;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.authentication.HttpAuthenticationFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
import com.rest.dto.EarUnearmarkCollateralInput;

public class RestClientTest {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //
            sslRestClientGETReport();
            //
            sslRestClientPostEarmark();
            //
            sslRestClientGETRankColl();
            //
        } catch (KeyManagementException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //
    private static WebTarget    target      = null;
    private static String       userName    = "username";
    private static String       passWord    = "password";

    //
    public static void sslRestClientGETReport() throws KeyManagementException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        //
        //
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = { new InsecureTrustManager() };
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new InsecureHostnameVerifier();
        //
        Client c = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sc).hostnameVerifier(allHostsValid).build();
        //
        String baseUrl = "https://localhost:7002/VaquarKhanWeb/employee/api/v1/informations/report";
        c.register(HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic(userName, passWord));
        target = c.target(baseUrl);
        target.register(new LoggingFilter());
        String responseMsg = target.request().get(String.class);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(responseMsg);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------");
        //

    }

    public static void sslRestClientGET() throws KeyManagementException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        //Query param Search={JSON}
        //
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = { new InsecureTrustManager() };
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new InsecureHostnameVerifier();
        //
        Client c = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sc).hostnameVerifier(allHostsValid).build();
        //
        String baseUrl = "https://localhost:7002/VaquarKhanWeb";

        //
        c.register(HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic(userName, passWord));
        target = c.target(baseUrl);
        target = target.path("employee/api/v1/informations/employee/data").queryParam("search","%7B\"name\":\"vaquar\",\"surname\":\"khan\",\"age\":\"30\",\"type\":\"admin\""%7D");

        target.register(new LoggingFilter());
        String responseMsg = target.request().get(String.class);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(responseMsg);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------");
        //

    }
    //TOD need to fix
    public static void sslRestClientPost() throws KeyManagementException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        //
        //
        Employee employee = new Employee("vaquar", "khan", "30", "E");
        //
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = { new InsecureTrustManager() };
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new InsecureHostnameVerifier();
        //
        Client c = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sc).hostnameVerifier(allHostsValid).build();
        //
        String baseUrl = "https://localhost:7002/VaquarKhanWeb/employee/api/v1/informations/employee";
        c.register(HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic(userName, passWord));
        target = c.target(baseUrl);
        target.register(new LoggingFilter());
        //
        Response response = target.request().put(Entity.json(employee));
        String output = response.readEntity(String.class);
        //
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(output);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------");

    }


}
```

Jars

```
repository/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar"
    repository/org/glassfish/jersey/core/jersey-client/2.6/jersey-client-2.6.jar"
    repository/org/glassfish/jersey/core/jersey-common/2.6/jersey-common-2.6.jar"
    repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-api/2.2.0/hk2-api-2.2.0.jar"
    repository/org/glassfish/jersey/bundles/repackaged/jersey-guava/2.6/jersey-guava-2.6.jar"
    repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-locator/2.2.0/hk2-locator-2.2.0.jar"
    repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-utils/2.2.0/hk2-utils-2.2.0.jar"
    repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.15.0-GA/javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar"
    repository/org/glassfish/hk2/external/javax.inject/2.2.0/javax.inject-2.2.0.jar"
    repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar"
    genson-1.3.jar"
```

Comment: Thanks for the great level of detail!

Answer (score 15):

For Jersey 2 you'd need to modify the code:

```
        return ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
            .withConfig(config)
            .hostnameVerifier(new TrustAllHostNameVerifier())
            .sslContext(ctx)
            .build();
```

https://gist.github.com/JAlexoid/b15dba31e5919586ae51
http://www.panz.in/2015/06/jersey2https.html

Comment: code provided is clean and works very well on jersey 2.22.1. Thanks

Comment: The linked gist is the best example of a solution with jersey 2.

Answer (score 10):

Waking up a dead question here but the answers provided will not work with jdk 7 (I read somewhere that a bug is open for this for Oracle Engineers but not fixed yet). Along with the link that @Ryan provided, you will have to also add :

> System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");

(Courtesy to many stackoverflow answers combined together to figure this out)

The complete code will look as follows which worked for me (without setting the system property the Client Config did not work for me):

```java
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.HTTPSProperties;
public class ClientHelper
{
    public static ClientConfig configureClient()
    {
        System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");
        TrustManager[] certs = new TrustManager[]
        {
            new X509TrustManager()
            {
                @Override
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
                {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                        throws CertificateException
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                        throws CertificateException
                {
                }
            }
        };
        SSLContext ctx = null;
        try
        {
            ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            ctx.init(null, certs, new SecureRandom());
        }
        catch (java.security.GeneralSecurityException ex)
        {
        }
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(ctx.getSocketFactory());
        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        try
        {
            config.getProperties().put(HTTPSProperties.PROPERTY_HTTPS_PROPERTIES, new HTTPSProperties(
                    new HostnameVerifier()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            },
                    ctx));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        return config;
    }

    public static Client createClient()
    {
        return Client.create(ClientHelper.configureClient());
    }
```

Comment: Could you please provide the imports you used in your class?

Comment: @MBarni - import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.HTTPSProperties;

import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Java 8, a shorter version for Jersey2 than the answer provided by Aleksandr.

```
SSLContext sslContext = null;
try {
  sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
  // Create a new X509TrustManager
  sslContext.init(null, getTrustManager(), null);
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
  throw e;
}
final Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().hostnameVerifier((s, session) -> true)
  .sslContext(sslContext).build();
return client;

private TrustManager[] getTrustManager() {
  return new TrustManager[] {
    new X509TrustManager() {
      @Override
      public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
      }
      @Override
      public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
      throws CertificateException {
      }
      @Override
      public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
      throws CertificateException {
      }
    }
  };
}
```