# Jersey client handshake error

Tags: java, rest, ssl, basic-authentication, jersey-client

When my client application tries to request a resource from my secure rest web service, I get the error pasted below.

I have found this answer on the topic, but the extra code seems extreme. 
[Accessing secure restful web services using jersey client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434309/accessing-secure-restful-web-services-using-jersey-client)
Does anyone know of a simpler way of solving the problem?

My project:
On the server side, I am using basic authentication using jdbc realm which is working fine when used in the browser. On the client side I set the username and password fine and the error occurs when I sent the request.
If you need code snippets, please ask. 
Thanks for your time.

```
 Aug 01, 2013 7:00:09 PM com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 1 * Client out-bound request
1 > GET https://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/resources/helloWorld
1 > Accept: text/html
1 > Authorization: Basic ZGF2aWQ6bXVycmF5

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:149)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LoggingFilter.handle(LoggingFilter.java:183)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter.handle(HTTPBasicAuthFilter.java:81)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:670)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:503)
    at secure_rest_hello_client.rest_secure_client.getXml(rest_secure_client.java:42)
    at secure_rest_hello_client.test_client.jButton1ActionPerformed(test_client.java:72)
    at secure_rest_hello_client.test_client.access$000(test_client.java:11)
    at secure_rest_hello_client.test_client$1.actionPerformed(test_client.java:39)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:912)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1294)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1321)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1305)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:523)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1296)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:240)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:147)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:352)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:893)
    ... 56 more
```

Comment: Found the problem, was using http instead of https.

Answer (score 0):

Your SSL connection was no setup at all. The handshaking procedure for setting up the SSL
connection failed. This can happen:
* if you do a non -SSL request (http) on a https listener port
* if the server is configured for security checks (e.g. client side certficate) which have not been fulfilled 
* other negotation issues
Mostly these issues can be checked with a curl or openssl command line client. Only if things work o.k. using curl and/or openssl you might want to look in issues with your code (which you didn't show in your question)