# how to add authentication filter\header to `com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client`?

Tags: java, rest, http, authentication, jersey

how can I add authentication filter\header to

`com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client` ?

I'm using `jersey-bundle-1.18.2`

i saw two posts:

1) [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774506/jersey-client-api-authentication):

```
client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(user, password));
```

2) [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434309/accessing-secure-restful-web-services-using-jersey-client):

```
client.setUsernamePassword("testClient", "secret");
```

but non of them apply to the above `Client` class.

These method don't exist in this type.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to execute `addFilter` after a builder method that returns `Webresource`

So I changed:

```
        client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(RT_USERNAME, RT_PASSWORD);

        ClientResponse clientResponse = client
                .resource(resource)
                .queryParam("confirm", "true")
                .queryParam("id", alertId)
.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(RT_USERNAME, RT_PASSWORD)...
```

to

```
client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(RT_USERNAME, RT_PASSWORD);

ClientResponse clientResponse = client
        .resource(resource)
        .queryParam("confirm", "true")
        .queryParam("id", alertId)
```