# Java: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have a class that will download a file from a **https** server. When I run  it, it returns a lot of errors. It seems that I have a problem with my certificate. Is it possible to ignore the client-server authentication? If so, how?

```
package com.da;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultHttpAsyncClient;
import org.apache.http.nio.IOControl;
import org.apache.http.nio.client.HttpAsyncClient;
import org.apache.http.nio.client.methods.AsyncCharConsumer;
import org.apache.http.nio.client.methods.HttpAsyncGet;
import org.apache.http.nio.client.methods.HttpAsyncPost;

public class RSDDownloadFile {
    static FileOutputStream fos;

    public void DownloadFile(String URI, String Request) throws Exception
    {
        java.net.URI uri = URIUtils.createURI("https", "176.66.3.69:6443", -1, "download.aspx",
                "Lang=EN&AuthToken=package", null);
        System.out.println("URI Query: " + uri.toString());

        HttpAsyncClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpAsyncClient();
        httpclient.start();
        try {
            Future<Boolean> future = httpclient.execute(
                    new HttpAsyncGet(uri),
                    new ResponseCallback(), null);

            Boolean result = future.get();
            if (result != null && result.booleanValue()) {
                System.out.println("\nRequest successfully executed");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Request failed");
            }              
        } 
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("[DownloadFile] Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("Shutting down");
            httpclient.shutdown();
        }
        System.out.println("Done");  

    }

    static class ResponseCallback extends AsyncCharConsumer<Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onResponseReceived(final HttpResponse response) {
             System.out.println("Response: " + response.getStatusLine());
             System.out.println("Header: " + response.toString());
             try {   
                 //if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200)
                     fos = new FileOutputStream( "Response.html" );
             }catch(Exception e){
                 System.out.println("[onResponseReceived] Exception: " + e.getMessage());
             }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCharReceived(final CharBuffer buf, final IOControl ioctrl) throws IOException {
            try
            {
                while (buf.hasRemaining()) 
                {
                    //System.out.print(buf.get());
                    fos.write(buf.get());
                }
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("[onCharReceived] Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCleanup() {
            try
            {             
                if(fos!=null)
                    fos.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("[onCleanup] Exception: " + e.getMessage());         
            }
             System.out.println("onCleanup()");
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean buildResult() {
            return Boolean.TRUE;
        }

    }
}
```

Errors:

```
URI Query: https://176.66.3.69:6443/download.aspx?Lang=EN&AuthToken=package
Aug 2, 2011 3:47:57 PM org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.NHttpClientProtocolHandler exception
SEVERE: I/O error: General SSLEngine problem
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:154)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:276)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalClientEventDispatch.inputReady(InternalClientEventDispatch.java:79)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:161)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:335)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:275)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:542)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:180)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.JsseX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 21 more
onCleanup()

[DownloadFile] Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
Shutting down
Done
```

Comment: One time I got this error and contacted our security team, and it turned out I had to patch the JAR we were using, as our team was using an outdated one provided by the company. Just an FYI for anyone else who may be in a similar situation.

Comment: I received this PKIX issue in two cases on while downloading the maven dependency directly from the internet instead of my organisation cache. This was resolved correcting the setting.xml file. Second time, i faced this issue when i was trying hitting Microsoft uri for oAuth token, this was resolved by adding cacert file in my jdk path

Answer (score 289):

The problem appears when your server has self signed certificate. To workaround it you can add this certificate to the list of trusted certificates of your JVM.

[In this article](http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/ssl/pkix_path_building_failed.html) author describes how to fetch the certificate from your browser and add it to cacerts file of your JVM. You can either edit `JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts` file or run you application with `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` parameter. Verify which JDK/JRE you are using too as this is often a source of confusion.

See also: [How are SSL certificate server names resolved/Can I add alternative names using keytool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443081/how-are-ssl-certificate-server-names-resolved-can-i-add-alternative-names-using) If you run into `java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found` exception.

Comment: this hasn't worked for me. I have the root and the chain cert installed, but Tomcat-7 still reports validatorException caused by "unable to find valid certification path to requested target" any way to debug this?

Comment: The problem also appears with a certificate signed by someone else that isn't trusted.

Comment: Great! It works! Just don't forget that you could have both jre and jdk, and both their `cacerts` must be updated

Comment: In my case, the root CA was there but not the next CA down.  Adding the next CA down did the trick - thanks.

Comment: In my case, I'm using Netbeans + Apache Tomcat (integrated), so, adding .cer to the trust store "cacerts" on Jdk/jre (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\security) and Jre (C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\security) works for me

Comment: Giving the `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` parameter is crucial to ensure, your application is loading the right cacerts file. (If problems occur, I recommend to try this first.) This resolves the case described by Dima Fomin too.

Answer (score 197):

Here's what reliably works for me on **macOS**. Make sure to replace example.com and 443 with the actual hostname and port you're trying to connect to, and give a custom alias. The first command downloads the provided certificate from the remote server and saves it locally in x509 format. The second command loads the saved certificate into Java's SSL trust store.

```
openssl x509 -in <(openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -prexit 2>/dev/null) -out ~/example.crt
sudo keytool -importcert -file ~/example.crt -alias example -keystore $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
```

Under **Windows** via **Git Bash or WSL** the first command looks a bit different :

```
openssl s_client -connect git.css.ch:443  -prexit > ~/cert.txt
openssl x509 -in ~/cert.txt -out ~/example.crt
```

Comment: Works for me why? You need to provide an explanation.

Comment: openssl x509 -in <(openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -prexit 2>/dev/null) -out ~/example.crt - what is example.crt in the command i have a .pem certificate i need to give that here ??

Comment: .crt and .pem are commonly used file extensions for the same file format. If you already have the file, just run the second command and pass it into the -file argument.

Comment: Great stuff. Only thing is: I had to use latest openssl 1.0.Xx for some reason, old 9.X.Xx wasn't working.

Comment: This doesn't work with SNI endpoint. For that case you need to add: -servername example.com when fetching the cert

Comment: Brilliant. Works for me in Windows 10 and JDK 1.8 too.

Comment: Based on installation, there may not be `/jre` but the rest should work on mac

Answer (score 59):

1. Export the SSL certificate using Firefox. You can export it by hitting the URL in the browser and then select the option to export the certificate. Let's assume the cert file name is **your.ssl.server.name.crt**
2. Go to your `JRE_HOME/bin` or `JDK/JRE/bin`
3. Type the command
4. `keytool -keystore ..\lib\security\cacerts -import -alias your.ssl.server.name -file .\relative-path-to-cert-file\your.ssl.server.name.crt`
5. Restart your Java process

Comment: If asked for a password, use the default cacerts keystore password `changeit` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/22782035/1304830). Also be sure to run cmd as administrator.

Answer (score 55):

I had the same issue with a valid signed wildcard certificate from symantec.

First try running your java application with ***-Djavax.net.debug=SSL*** to see what is really going on.

I ended up ***importing the intermediate certificate*** which was causing the cert chain to break.

I downloaded the missing intermediate cert from symantec (you can see the download link to the missing cert in the ssl handshake log: http://svrintl-g3-aia.verisign.com/SVRIntlG3.cer in my case).

And I imported the cert in the java keystore. After importing the intermediate certificate my wildcard ssl cert finally started working:

```
keytool -import -keystore ../jre/lib/security/cacerts -trustcacerts -alias "VeriSign Class 3 International Server CA - G3" -file /pathto/SVRIntlG3.cer
```

Comment: This was the case:

Comment: To avoid confusion, run java (or jcurl) with debug parameters to see remote "Certificate chain" in logs, then grep the "CN" in truststore explicitly passed (instead of default) as follows, if not present, you need to add. https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html will show if server side certs has incomplete chain, and includes intermediate certification path certificates that need to be added.


`-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=our-client-certs -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=their-server-certs`

Comment: And, of course, the official article to debug SSL issues:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html
https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https

Comment: I had the same issue, this is very useful, but in my case you only had to add the server certificate to cacerts file of the JDK version

Comment: Please keep in mind that there is another tool called portecle which can open the cacert file (certificate store) and import the certificate easily. Just remember to save the cacert file afterwards.

Answer (score 38):

@Gabe Martin-Dempesy's answer is helped to me. And I wrote a small script related to it. The usage is very simple.

Install a certificate from host:

```
> sudo ./java-cert-importer.sh example.com
```

Remove the certificate that installed already.

```
> sudo ./java-cert-importer.sh example.com --delete
```

**java-cert-importer.sh**

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Exit on error
set -e

# Ensure script is running as root
if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]
  then echo "WARN: Please run as root (sudo)"
  exit 1
fi

# Check required commands
command -v openssl >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo "Required command 'openssl' not installed. Aborting." >&2; exit 1; }
command -v keytool >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo "Required command 'keytool' not installed. Aborting." >&2; exit 1; }

# Get command line args
host=$1; port=${2:-443}; deleteCmd=${3:-${2}}

# Check host argument
if [ ! ${host} ]; then
cat << EOF
Please enter required parameter(s)

usage:  ./java-cert-importer.sh <host> [ <port> | default=443 ] [ -d | --delete ]

EOF
exit 1
fi;

if [ "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
    javahome=${JAVA_HOME}
elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "linux-gnu" ]]; then # Linux
    javahome=$(readlink -f $(which java) | sed "s:bin/java::")
elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then # Mac OS X
    javahome="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre"
fi

if [ ! "$javahome" ]; then
    echo "WARN: Java home cannot be found."
    exit 1
elif [ ! -d "$javahome" ]; then
    echo "WARN: Detected Java home does not exists: $javahome"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Detected Java Home: $javahome"

# Set cacerts file path
cacertspath=${javahome}/lib/security/cacerts
cacertsbackup="${cacertspath}.$$.backup"

if ( [ "$deleteCmd" == "-d" ] || [ "$deleteCmd" == "--delete" ] ); then
    sudo keytool -delete -alias ${host} -keystore ${cacertspath} -storepass changeit
    echo "Certificate is deleted for ${host}"
    exit 0
fi

# Get host info from user
#read -p "Enter server host (E.g. example.com) : " host
#read -p "Enter server port (Default 443) : " port

# create temp file
tmpfile="/tmp/${host}.$$.crt"

# Create java cacerts backup file
cp ${cacertspath} ${cacertsbackup}

echo "Java CaCerts Backup: ${cacertsbackup}"

# Get certificate from speficied host
openssl x509 -in <(openssl s_client -connect ${host}:${port} -prexit 2>/dev/null) -out ${tmpfile}

# Import certificate into java cacerts file
sudo keytool -importcert -file ${tmpfile} -alias ${host} -keystore ${cacertspath} -storepass changeit

# Remove temp certificate file
rm ${tmpfile}

# Check certificate alias name (same with host) that imported successfully
result=$(keytool -list -v -keystore ${cacertspath} -storepass changeit | grep "Alias name: ${host}")

# Show results to user
if [ "$result" ]; then
    echo "Success: Certificate is imported to java cacerts for ${host}";
else
    echo "Error: Something went wrong";
fi;
```

Comment: Works flawlessly. Great job! . This is how it works: start your SSL service (if its not running), and execute the command as explained (e.g. `./java-cert-importer.sh example.com 1234`). That's it.

Comment: Works great. I was getting the error on a Jenkins server connecting to an external API which changes his certificate and fails my builts. This solves my issue

Comment: Oracle should have provided something like this in the first place or never every created their own horrible SSL solution. SSL certificate handling should be an operating system's job.

Comment: Thank you @bhdrk.

Comment: Thank you very much! I want to make a couple of edits that helped me. 1. Do not forget that when starting from su JAVA_HOME is different 2. In cacertspath = $ {javahome}/lib/security/cacerts, you may need to insert a /jre/, that is, cacertspath =${javahome}/jre/lib/security/cacerts

Answer (score 20):

Quoting from [No more 'unable to find valid certification path to requested target'](http://cold-caffein.blogspot.com/2011/07/looks-like-article-no-more-unable-to.html)

> when trying to open an SSL connection to a host using JSSE. What this usually means is that the server is using a test certificate (possibly generated using keytool) rather than a certificate from a well known commercial Certification Authority such as Verisign or GoDaddy. Web browsers display warning dialogs in this case, but since JSSE cannot assume an interactive user is present it just throws an exception by default.
>
> Certificate validation is a very important part of SSL security, but I am not writing this entry to explain the details. If you are interested, you can start by reading the Wikipedia blurb. I am writing this entry to show a simple way to talk to that host with the test certificate, if you really want to.
>
> Basically, you want to add the server's certificate to the KeyStore with your trusted certificates

Try the code provided there. It might help.

Comment: The part about "Certificate validation is a very important part of SSL security" is not necessarily true.  SSL gives you two assurances: (1) that your communication is private, and (2) that you are talking to a server which is known to the NSA.(:-)  Sometimes you only care about privacy of the conversation, and then a self-signed certification is fine.  See http://social-biz.org/2011/10/16/the-anti-ssl-conspiracy/

Comment: @AgilePro SSL gives you *four* assurances: authentication, privacy, integrity, and the possibilty of authorization. It does *not* give you any assurance that you are talking to a server known to the NSA. Caring only about privacy without authentication is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @EJP Agree that if you use a client certificate you can get authentication and I suppose the possibility of authorization ... but most uses are not with a client certificate.  What would you call the difference between a "self-signed" certificate, and a certificate from a signing authority?   Does signing authority give "integrity".  My Joke about NSA is that all signing authorities can not positively guarantee independence from everything.  Not that paranoid really, but the point is your certificate is ONLY as secret as the signing authority can make it.  Self-signed can be more secret.

Comment: @AgilePro Using a *server* certificate authenticates the server, and is *required* to make SSL secure, as noted in RFC 2246. Certificates are not secret at all: therefore remainder of your comment makes no sense.

Answer (score 12):

**Simple Steps that I followed.**

***problem:*** I was trying to connect to an endpoint(https://%s.blob.core.windows.net) using a simple java class(main method).

So I was getting this certification issue as mentioned above, in the question.

***Solution:***

1. Get the certificate using a browser(chrome). To do this paste your endpoint URL in the browser and enter. Now you will see a lock icon, click on that -->certificate--> details --> copy to files--> download it.
2. open the cmd(i am using windows) as admin and then navigate to the directory where you have downloaded the .cer file.

3.(Optional)If you are using multiple JDK in the same machine then change your JDK version the same as you are using in your application.

4. Now use the below command

> keytool -import -alias mycertificate -keystore "C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk-11.0.5\lib\security\cacerts" -file myurlcrt.cer

5. Give the default password: *changeit*
6. Trust this certificate: yes

And you are done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

This solved my issue,

We need to import the cert onto the local java. If not we could get the below exception.

```
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
```

[SSLPOKE](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/files/779355358/779355357/1/1441897666313/SSLPoke.class) is a tool where you can test the https connectivity from your local machine.

Command to test the connectivity:

```
"%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java" SSLPoke <hostname> 443
```

```
    sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
    sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:747)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:138)
        at SSLPoke.main(SSLPoke.java:31)
    Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to 
    requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
        ... 15 more
```

```
keytool -import -alias <anyname> -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -file <cert path>
```

this would first prompt to "Enter keystore password:" **`changeit`** is the default password. and finally a prompt "Trust this certificate? [no]:", provide "yes" to add the cert to keystore.

**Verfication:**

```
C:\tools>"%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java" SSLPoke <hostname> 443
Successfully connected
```

Comment: I did this but somehow it is showing the error log always

Answer (score 7):

For Windows only, follow these steps:

1. In Chrome go to settings.
2. In Settings click show advance settings.
3. Under HTTPS/SSL Click on Manage Certificates.
4. Export Your Certificate.
5. In Windows searchs (Pressing windows key on keyboard) type java.
6. Select (Configure Java) Option Which will open Java Control Panel
7. Select Security tab in Java Control Panel
8. Select Manage Certificates
9. Click Import
10. Under (User) tab selected and certificate type as (Trusted Certificates)
11. Click import button and browse to downloaded certificate and import it.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to get it working with code only, i.e. no need to use keytool:

```
import com.netflix.config.DynamicBooleanProperty;
import com.netflix.config.DynamicIntProperty;
import com.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.config.Registry;
import org.apache.http.config.RegistryBuilder;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContexts;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustStrategy;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.X509HostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.HttpAsyncClients;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.IOReactorConfig;
import org.apache.http.nio.conn.NoopIOSessionStrategy;
import org.apache.http.nio.conn.SchemeIOSessionStrategy;
import org.apache.http.nio.conn.ssl.SSLIOSessionStrategy;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLException;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class Test
{
    private static final DynamicIntProperty MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS = DynamicPropertyFactory.getInstance().getIntProperty("X.total.connections", 40);
    private static final DynamicIntProperty ROUTE_CONNECTIONS = DynamicPropertyFactory.getInstance().getIntProperty("X.total.connections", 40);
    private static final DynamicIntProperty CONNECT_TIMEOUT = DynamicPropertyFactory.getInstance().getIntProperty("X.connect.timeout", 60000);
    private static final DynamicIntProperty SOCKET_TIMEOUT = DynamicPropertyFactory.getInstance().getIntProperty("X.socket.timeout", -1);
    private static final DynamicIntProperty CONNECTION_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = DynamicPropertyFactory.getInstance().getIntProperty("X.connectionrequest.timeout", 60000);
    private static final DynamicBooleanProperty STALE_CONNECTION_CHECK = DynamicPropertyFactory.getInstance().getBooleanProperty("X.checkconnection", true);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
                .useTLS()
                .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustStrategy()
                {
                    @Override
                    public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                })
                .build();
        SSLIOSessionStrategy sslSessionStrategy = new SSLIOSessionStrategy(sslcontext, new AllowAll());

        Registry<SchemeIOSessionStrategy> sessionStrategyRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<SchemeIOSessionStrategy>create()
                .register("http", NoopIOSessionStrategy.INSTANCE)
                .register("https", sslSessionStrategy)
                .build();

        DefaultConnectingIOReactor ioReactor = new DefaultConnectingIOReactor(IOReactorConfig.DEFAULT);
        PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager(ioReactor, sessionStrategyRegistry);
        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS.get());
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(ROUTE_CONNECTIONS.get());

        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setSocketTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT.get())
                .setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT.get())
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(CONNECTION_REQUEST_TIMEOUT.get())
                .setStaleConnectionCheckEnabled(STALE_CONNECTION_CHECK.get())
                .build();

        CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpClient = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
                .setSSLStrategy(sslSessionStrategy)
                .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                .build();

        httpClient.start();

        // use httpClient...
    }

    private static class AllowAll implements X509HostnameVerifier
    {
        @Override
        public void verify(String s, SSLSocket sslSocket) throws IOException
        {}

        @Override
        public void verify(String s, X509Certificate x509Certificate) throws SSLException {}

        @Override
        public void verify(String s, String[] strings, String[] strings2) throws SSLException
        {}

        @Override
        public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw, I'm using httpasyncclient:4.0.1

Comment: I needed something similar, @JonasBergström, your solution with SSLContext help a lot.

Comment: Note that this solution is insecure.

Comment: Thank you Jonas, your solution does solved the problem. But I found it costs a very long time (3 - 5s) to create the first connection, after that every connection only need 300-400 ms.

Answer (score 6):

The source of this error on my Apache 2.4 instance (using a Comodo wildcard certificate) was an incomplete path to the SHA-1 signed root certificate. There were multiple chains in the issued certificate, and the chain leading to a SHA-1 root certificate was missing an [intermediate certificate](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/966/108/intermediate-1-sha-2-comodo-rsa-certification-authority). Modern browsers know how to handle this, but Java 7 doesn't handle it by default (although there are some convoluted ways to accomplish this in code). The result is error messages that look identical to the case of self-signed certificates:

```
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    ... 22 more
```

In this case, the "unable to find valid certification path to requested target" message is being produced due to the missing intermediate certificate. You can check which certificate is missing using [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) test against the server. Once you find the appropriate certificate, download it and (if the server is under your control) add it to the certificate bundle. Alternatively, you can import the missing certificate locally. Accommodating this issue on the server is a more general solution to the problem.

Comment: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ is a savior, just have to compare it with a working cert validation.

Answer (score 5):

There is a lot of way to solve this...

One way is set the TrustStore certificates in a keystore file and put it in the path of the application, and set these system properties in the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "trust-store.jks");
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "TrustStore");
  ...
}
```

Other way is place the keystore as resource file inside the project jar file and load it:

```
public static SSLContext createSSLContext(String resourcePath, String pass) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, IOException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException {
  // initialise the keystore
  final char[] password = pass.toCharArray();
  KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
  ks.load(ThisClass.class.getResourceAsStream(resourcePath
  ), password);

  // Setup the key manager factory.
  KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
  kmf.init(ks, password);

  // Setup the trust manager factory.
  TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
  tmf.init(ks);

  SSLContext sslc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
  sslc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
  return sslc;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  SSLContext.setDefault(
    createSSLContext("/trust-store.jks", "TrustStore"));
  ...
}
```

In windows you can try this solution too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59056537/980442

---

I created the keystore file from a Certificate authority CA `.crt` file in this way:

```
keytool -import -alias ca -keystore trust-store.jks -storepass TrustStore -trustcacerts -file ca.crt
```

FYI: https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/adminguide/cadminsslclient.html

Answer (score 5):

Had the issue like this image.

[image]

Tried a few solutions.
But found that even if it's same project, when it's on other one's working place, it's totally fine. No extra settings needed. So we guessed it's an enviroment issue. We tried changing JDK version, IDE but didn't work. it took about 4 hours for investigation, until we tried the top-rated answer. I didn't find the error mentioned in that answer but I found via my browser about HTTP URL (lock) that there was a certification of Charles. Then I realized my charles was on all the time. As long as I turned that off, it's working all fine.

So I left my experience that could be helpful for your case.

Answer (score 4):

For those who like Debian and prepackaged Java:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/ca-certificates/test/  # don't mess with other certs
sudo cp ~/tmp/test.loc.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/test/
sudo dpkg-reconfigure --force ca-certificates  # check your cert in curses GUI!
sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh --verbose
```

Don't forget to check `/etc/default/cacerts` for:

```
# enable/disable updates of the keystore /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
cacerts_updates=yes
```

To remove cert:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/ca-certificates/test/test.loc.crt
sudo rm /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh --verbose
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with the certificates error and it was because of SNI: the http client that I used didn't have SNI implemented. So a version update did the job

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:** That a reboot helped was coincidental (I hoped so, hooray!). The real cause of the problem was this: When Gradle is directed to use a specific  keystore, that keystore must also contain all the official root certificates. Otherwise it cannot access libraries from regular repositories. What I had to do was this:

Import the self-signed certificate:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias myselfsignedcert -file /Users/me/Desktop/selfsignedcert.crt -keystore ./privateKeystore.jks
```

Add the official root certificates:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore <java-home>/lib/security/cacerts -destkeystore ./privateKeystore.jks
```

Maybe the Gradle daemon also got in the way. Might be worth killing all running daemons found with `./gradlew --status` if things start looking bleak.

**ORIGINAL POSTING:**

Nobody will believe this, I know. Still, if all else fails, give it a try:
After a **reboot** of my Mac the problem was gone. Grrr.

Background:
./gradlew jar kept giving me "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

I am stuck with a self-signed certificate, saved from browser, imported in privateKeystore.jks. Then instructed Gradle to work with privateKeystore.jks:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Djavax.net.debug=SSL -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="/Users/me/IntelliJ/myproject/privateKeystore.jks"  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

As mentioned, this only worked after a reboot.

Answer (score 2):

This can also be caused by using GoDaddy certs with Java 7 that are signed using SHA2.

Chrome and all other browsers are starting to deprecate SSL certs that are signed using SHA1, as it's not as secure.

More info [on the issue can be found here](http://tozny.com/blog/godaddys-ssl-certs-dont-work-in-java-the-right-solution/), as well as how to resolve it on your server if you need to now.

Answer (score 2):

AVG version 18.1.3044 (with Windows 10) interfer with my local Spring application.

**Solution:** enter in AVG section called "Web and email" and disable the "email protection".
AVG block the certificate if the site isn't secure.

Answer (score 2):

```
Download the certificate from Nexus3 Browser (click on the lock-pad for View Site Information in case of Edge broser)
Click on Connection is secure
Click on the certificate details
Click on Copy To file (it opens up export certificate wizard)
Choose Base-64 encoding
Browse and select a download location and file-name (let’s say mycert)
Open cmd
Goto the download location and execute the below command
keytool -import -alias mycert -keystore  "<<your-JAVA_HOME-directory>>\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -file mycert.cer
Restart the machine
Execute maven build again.
```

Answer (score 2):

**And if you are here in 2022 and are on mac follow this**

**1. Download the certificate.**

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect <ServerName>:<PORT> -servername <ServerName> \
    | openssl x509 > /tmp/<ServerName>.cert
```

**2. Find your JDK path by executing the command.**

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

**3. Now import the cert into the cert-store of jdk.**

```
sudo keytool -import -alias mycertificate -keystore "<JDK_HOME>/lib/security/cacerts" -file /tmp/<ServerName>.cert
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, import the self-signed cert into java's keystore for each jvm the software will run on or try the non-validating ssl factory:

```
jdbc:postgresql://myserver.com:5432/mydatabasename?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the https://176.66.3.69:6443/ have a valid certificate.
you can check it via browser firstly [image: https not secure] if it works in browser it will work in java.

that is working for me

Comment: And what should I do if browser also complains?

Comment: try to install the certificate

Comment: In my case browser is okay, but still, I am getting error in java

Answer (score 1):

As original question was - how to ignore the cert error, here is solution for those using SpringBoot and RestTemplate

```
@Service
public class SomeService {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;    

    private static HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory() {
        try {
            SSLContextBuilder sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder();
            sslContext.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustAllStrategy());
            CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext.build()).setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE).build();
            HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
            requestFactory.setHttpClient(client);
            return requestFactory;
        } catch (KeyManagementException | KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException var3) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Couldn't create HTTP Request factory ignore SSL cert validity: ", var3);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    public SomeService(RestTemplate restTemplate, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.dimetorURL = dimetorURL;
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(createRequestFactory());
    }


    public ResponseEntity<ResponseObject> sendRequest(RequestObject requestObject) {
        //...
        return restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, ResponseObject.class);
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Fixed the SSL issue in my case, thnx!

Answer (score 1):

If getting this error in maven, or maven with TestNG :

1. download the certificate from the target website and install certificate on your machine (using keytool as suggested above, or on windows)
2. add the following content to the maven arguments (command line and/or IDE):
   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Users\me.keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=X
   Where X is the password you used at the keytool step.

note : C:\Users\me.keystore should also be set to match your machine.
For instance :

```
mvn -ea -Dtestng.dtd.http=true  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Users\me\.keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=X -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true -Dcucumber.features=src/test/resources -Dcucumber.glue=com.myapp -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@MY_TEST"
```

Answer (score 1):

This works on any OS you just need JDK installed :

1. Download the certificate from the remote server :

   `keytool -printcert -rfc -sslserver <your remote server hostname> > /tmp/remorte-cert.crt`
2. Import the certificate to your JDK keystore :

   `keytool -importcert -file /tmp/remorte-cert.crt -alias <an alias for your remote server> -storepass changeit -keystore "${JAVA_HOME}/lib/security/cacerts" -noprompt`

Comment: what if the site does not have a valid certificate can you turn off valid certificate check

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm running MacOs High Sierra with Java 1.6. The cacert file is in a different location than referenced above in Gabe Martin-Dempesy's answer. The cacert file was also already linked to another location (/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts).

Using FireFox, I exported the certificate from the web site in question to a local file called "exportedCertFile.crt". From there, I used keytool to move the certificate into the cacert file. This fixed the problem.

```
bash-3.2# cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/
bash-3.2# keytool -importcert -file ~/exportedCertFile.crt -alias example -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit
```

Answer (score 0):

first Download the ssl certificate then you can go to your java bin path execute the below command in the console.

```
C:\java\JDK1.8.0_66-X64\bin>keytool -printcert -file C:\Users\lova\openapi.cer -keystore openapistore
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had both keystore and truststore having the same certificate so removing truststore helped. Sometimes the chain of certificates can be an issue if you've multiple copies of certificates.

Comment: Are you saying you can just completely remove the truststore and not even have to deal with certificates? If so, I'd love to know, because these certificate issues do nothing but steal my productivity and waste countless hours of my time.

Comment: if you have keystore then possibly yes. You need to have cert in one of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me on macOS. Replace server-name and server-port with your own.

Run these two commands on your terminal.

## Download certificate from the remote server

```
openssl x509 -in <(openssl s_client -connect server-name:server-port -prexit 2>/dev/null) -out ~/server-name.crt
```

## Import cert to Java keystore

```
sudo keytool -importcert -file ~/server-name.crt -alias server-name -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
```

Restart your application and the certs errors should go away!

Comment: How to know my server name and server port?

Comment: @lucky The server you are trying to connect to have that information