# keytool error Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: java, keystore

I am getting following error while generating certificates on my local machine.

```
C:\Users\abc>keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
Enter keystore password:
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

I think there is some problems in jdk version.I ran the same command on my collegues machine and it is working fine.

Please share your inputs.

Comment: are you giving correct password? and running the command from proper directory?

Comment: As I am creating it, so I am entering a new password.From which directory should I run it?

Comment: keytool -genkeypair -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore D:\keystore.jks try this for generating keystore and then export cer like

keytool -export -alias mycert -keystore D:\keystore.jks -file vorburger.cer

Comment: Can you please clarify, does it will have the same effect as was with "keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA".

Comment: can you tell me the purpose of generating this cer?

Comment: I am using it inside server.xml of Tomcat7.0 for SSL.

Comment: For mac users http://stackoverflow.com/a/33603411/1348522

Answer (score 107, accepted):

From your description I assume you are on windows machine and your home is abc

**So Now : Cause**

When you run this command

`keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA`

because you are not specifying an explicit keystore it will try to generate (and in your case as you are getting exception so to update) keystore `C:\users\abc>.keystore` and of course you need to provide old password for .keystore while I believe you are providing  your version (a new one).

**Solution**

1. Either delete `.keystore` from `C:\users\abc>` location and try the command
2. or try following command which will create a new xyzkeystore:

   `keytool -genkey -keystore xyzkeystore -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA`

**Note:** `-genkey` is old now rather use `-genkeypair` althought both work equally.

Comment: Though I figured it out of my own. "Either delete .keystore from C:\users\abc> location and try the command" is the right solution.

Comment: is it possible to deliver the keystore pass in the arguments?

Comment: I have deleted the existing keystore file and then followed the command keytool -genkey -alias key0-keyalg RSA, then it asks me new password and others data, I gave. But still now, when I try to build signed apk, it shows the same error message -"Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
" What's the problem here?

Comment: If you are getting `keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: xyzkeystore (Permission denied)` run with sudo

Comment: @HashmatullahNoorzai, maybe need to open CMD as admin

Comment: This is the only correct  answer to the posed question. The other answers side step the question. Essentially a keystore ALREADY EXISTED with a different password.

Answer (score 429):

I solved it by using the default password for cacerts keystore : `'changeit'`

Comment: haha.. so actually its not change password to new one, and default work :D

Comment: thanks :)..it worked at my end..and i was using the password that I used to export the .cer file..

Comment: If it doesn't work, default password is: android

Answer (score 237):

## This answer will be helpful for new Mac User (Works for Linux, Window 7 64 bit too).

Empty Password worked in my mac . (paste the below line in terminal)

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

when it prompt for

```
Enter keystore password:
```

just press enter button (Dont type anything).It should work .

Please make sure its for default `debug.keystore`  file , not for your project based keystore file (Password might change for this).

Works well for MacOS Sierra 10.10+ too.

I heard, it works for linux environment as well. i haven't tested that in linux yet.

Comment: Thanks. It worked on my windows 10 for debug keystore

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. Using debug keystore on win 10 like Vinayak

Comment: I'm embarrassed by how many passwords I tried haha

Answer (score 47):

[According to the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth):

> The default password for the debug keystore is `android`.

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped! Indeed, "android" is a proper password if the keys are generated by Android Studio, not via the keytool per se, unlike default "changeit" password for the keytool.

Answer (score 26):

I have solve this issue by using default password "**changeit**".

Comment: This worked for me(in windows 10)

Answer (score 18):

Using changeit for the password is important too.

This command finally worked for me(with jetty):

```
 keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -storepass changeit -validity 360 -keysize 2048
```

Answer (score 15):

In tomcat 8.5 pay attention to write the correct name of attributes. This is my code on server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/keystore" certificateKeystorePassword="mypassword" type="RSA"/>
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

You can visit https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html to see all attributes

Answer (score 10):

If you are working on signing your Flutter App by following this guide [Build and release an Android app](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#create-a-keystore) and run in to this error. I hope this answer helps you.

In my case I changed the path to store my key.jks. This happened to me because I there was an existing file in that path.

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
```

This command stores the key.jks file in your home directory. To store it elsewhere, change the argument you pass to the -keystore parameter.

In my case,

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore /Users/Y/Desktop/X/key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias keyYour
```

i.e **Y** - Username and **X** - folder name

Then you will be prompted to **Enter keystore password:**  and **Re-enter new password:**. Here you can use whatever password you want.

**However, keep the keystore file private; don’t check it into public source control!**

Answer (score 6):

Empty password worked for me on my Mac

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

hit Enter then It's show you

```
Enter keystore password:
```

here just hit Enter for empty password

Comment: Not on my Mac (in 2021).

Comment: @SridharSarnobat are you using m1 ?

Comment: I've not heard of that. Only m1 finance!

Answer (score 5):

Check your home folder `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`. Sometimes if you have `gradle.properties` in home directory it takes details from the there. Either you can change that or delete the files. Then it will take required details from your local folder.

Answer (score 5):

Works on Windows

open command prompt (press Windows Key + R then type "cmd" without quotations in the appearing dialogue box and then press Enter Key).

then type the code sniff below :

1. cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin

then type following command

2. keytool -list -keystore "C:/Documents and Settings/Your Name/.android/debug.keystore"

Then it will ask for Keystore password now. The default password is
"android" type and enter  or just hit enter "DONT TYPE ANY PASSWORD".

Answer (score 4):

Summarizing the advices from this page, I finished up with the following:

```
keytool -genkeypair -keystore ~/.android/release.keystore -alias <my_alias> -storepass <my_cert_pass> -keyalg RSA
```

Then I got a set of questions regarding name, organization, location and password for my alias.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by deleting the output file and running the command again. It turns out it does NOT overwrite the previous file. I had this issue when renewing a let's encrypt cert with tomcat

Answer (score 2):

With openjdk I had the same problem.
After I updated openjdk to "11.0.17" the problem was gone.

Answer (score 1):

> keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

I solved my problem when I changed keystore path **C:\MyWorks\mykeystore** to **C:\MyWorks\mykeystore.keystore**.

Comment: the first path "C:\MyWorks\mykeystore" is not a keystore.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was needed to have `root` access.

Answer (score 1):

```
 [root@localhost Certificate]# openssl pkcs12 -export -in 
 /opt/Certificate/115c99f4c5aa98f5.crt -inkey /opt/Certificate/ravi.in.key -certfile 
/opt/Certificate/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt -out RaviNew.p12

Enter Export Password: <Password>
Verifying - Enter Export Password: <Password>
```

**Note :-** Above Export Pasworrd write down anywhere because it is must to create JKS file ( It is depend on your choice what password you want to make )

```
  keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore DigiEduNew.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore finaldigiEdu.jks -deststoretype JKS
  Importing keystore DigiEduNew.p12 to finaldigiEdu.jks...
  Enter destination keystore password: <Any Password >
  Re-enter new password: <Any Password >
  Enter source keystore password: <.P12 Password >
  Entry for alias 1 successfully imported.
  Import command completed:  1 entries successfully imported, 0 entries failed or 
  cancelled



 Warning:
 The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 
 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore 
 finaldigiEdu.jks -destkeystore finaldigiEdu.jks -deststoretype pkcs12".
```

Answer (score 1):

For me I solved it by changing passwords from Arabic letter to English letter, but first I went to the folder and deleted the generated key then it works.

Answer (score 1):

In my case with Xamarin Forms 4.7 and Visual Studio 2019 16.7.0 Preview 3.1, the problem was version mismatch of lately updated Android Build tools (apksigner) and JDK. Updated JDK to latest and pointed the new JDK path on Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android Settings, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

**you have two options:**

cmd doesn't show the password on the screen while typing
so just type the correct passwd -and be careful- then press enter.

**Or**
just use:

```
keytool -list -keystore 'keystoreName' -storepass 'type your keystore passwd'
```

**and** for Keys' full info, add `-v`:

```
keytool -v -list -keystore 'keystoreName' -storepass 'type your keystore passwd'
```

Answer (score 1):

For my case, there was another `upload-keystore.jks` file at the location where I was running the code. It was fixed when I deleted it and ran the code again.

Answer (score 0):

Just upgraded to Android Studio 4.2 from 4.0.  Apparently, Android Studio silently **CHANGED** my keystore password, which has been sitting there unchanged and working perfectly without incident for well over a year.

Just had to re-renter both passwords.

*Sigh*

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a `.store` file, you have to use the same password as you did to generate it. So in my case the solution was:

```
rm *.store
rm *.cer
```

That may sound odd to you but I'm just trying to learn about `keytool` and am source controlling my tutorial files and rerunning them later!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is helpful for those who manage multiple keystores across different projects.

I had the same error and I noticed I was using a file `keystore.jks` with the password of another `keystore.jks` which throws this exception since the password doesn't match.