# Error when trying to connect through SSL. Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, keytool

I am totally new to `web services`. I am tying to connect through `SSL` connection. I added the `certificate` to the `keystore` by the following:

```
keytool -importcert -alias <some name> -file <Certifacate path> -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -storepass changeit
```

and I checked it is exists by using `keytool -list` command

The problem is that I got this error message when I trying to connect through `SSL` in the application:

1. `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)`
2. `java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect`

and here is the `Java` code:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre7\\lib\\security\\keystore.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","changeit");
```

This Thread: [keytool error Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891182/keytool-error-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect) proposed a solution by re-generate the `keystore` file. But when I refer to the new `keystore.jks` it gives me

`java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty`

I am using `Jdeveloper 11g R1` and `JDK 7`, if that's help.

Comment: So 'changeit' is not the password of your keystore.jks file.

Comment: @EJP Most likely that's true. How do I know the password? I tried to change it but this did not work because it asks for the old one which I do not have. I also tried to create new keystore as I said in the question but it gives me the error mentioned

Comment: Do you need a keystore at all? Do you have a client certificate? Maybe you only need to set javax.net.ssl.trustStore, or indeed let it default, as you're using a default one.

Comment: @EJP I have the certificate as .cer file and I added it to the trusted certificate and to the keystore. I do not know how to know if it is required a keystore? how to do that?

Comment: If it's a certificate of another server that you want to connect, to, you only need to add it to your truststore. If it's a certificate you generated yourself, starting with a new keystore and a new key-pair, you will already have it in your own keystore and you would already know its password, and you would remember doing all those steps. You never add the same certificate to both a keystore and a truststore, so you're definitely doing something wrong. If you don't have your own key-pair and certificate, you don't need to specify a keystore at all.

Comment: @EJP OK I delete the certificate form the key store and delete the Java statements in the question. and I got this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Comment: That bizarre message means that the truststore you specified wasn't found or couldn't be opened. Check your setting of javax.net.ssl.trustStore. As I said above, you seem to be using the default one, in which case you don't need to specify it at all.

Comment: Problem solved by removing "javax.net.ssl.trustStore" statement. and now I am getting new errors. I will post new question about them if I need help.