# keytool: "Keystore was tampered with..." after adding Analytics to app

Tags: android, android-studio, google-analytics

I'm using Android Studio and i generated signed APKs multiple times.
Today i have add Google Analytics (according to [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) guide) to my app, and when i tried to generate a signed APK, suddenly i get the error `Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect`.
Then i deleted all the changes i had to to do for getting the Analytics to work, and i succeed to generate signed APK.

I saw some [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891182/keytool-error-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect)regarding the Keystore error i get, all use commands (such as `keytool -genkey -keystore ...`) but i'm generating the APK with `Build -> Generate Signed APK`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally i succeed to manage this issue.
The problem was indeed occurred after adding `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3'` to my project's top-level `build.gradle`, according to google [guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/).
The solution was to put the classpath to the app-level `build.gradle`.
Overall i had made no changes to the project's top-level `build.gradle`, and know my app-level `build.gradle` looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
//...
    buildTypes {
    //...
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.1.3.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3'
    }
}
```

This issue was also [reported](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=187532#makechanges)