# Android Studio 3.0 causing generate signed apk issues

Tags: android-studio, keystore, app-signing

I recently updated to Android Studio 3.0 and I'm having the following issue:

I have my `.jks` file and I'm trying to create a `signed apk.` I'm %100 sure that the Alias name and all passwords are correct but I'm getting an error that `Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect.`

I even tried creating a new key and that works one or two times but then I get the same message, can anyone explain what is happening here?

It seem s that this is happening as a result of the new Android Studio update - am I missing something about this update?

Comment: Did you try this : keytool -genkey -keystore xyzkeystore -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA

Comment: Not so familiar with Command Line - what does that do?

Comment: It will make you another key .Checkout this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891182/keytool-error-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect

Comment: But why would this error occur even with new keys that I create? And what is cause of this issue?

Comment: This may happen if your keystore password is incorrect

Comment: But as I said I even tested a new one and it works a couple times then spits out the same error?

Comment: Please check if you have you added correct `signingConfig` to the app's gradle file

Comment: @Amey What should the correct `signingConfig` be?

Answer (score 0):

Hey so the correct `siginingConfigs` would look something like this

```html
android {
  signingConfigs {
    release {
      storeFile file("PATH/TO/YOUR/FILE/mykeystore")
      storePassword "mypassword"
      keyAlias "KeyAlias"
      keyPassword "mypassword"
    }
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: So I looked through my whole project can't find where this `signingconfig` file is???

Comment: The way I usually create my signed apks is by clicking in Build -> Geneate signed APK and it works perfectly never had to deal with this file you are mentioning?

Comment: This is the google's recommended way of adding the keystore to the project. I know it was working without this before But they may have made it mandatory for new gradle version. Just try adding that to the app's gradle.

Comment: signingconfig is not a file. you have a keystore file. you need to add the above code snippet to the gradle file

Comment: Didn't work I don't think thats is necessary to do. Still not working.