# Android Studio APK Signing, Can't Click 'Next'

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, keystore

I somehow can't click on the 'Next' button while trying to sign my app.

[image]

I have followed the android developer guide and triple-checked everything but I simply can't move on.

I have also tried to write the wrong password and got this message:

```
Cannot load key store: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

That means the keystore path is right when I write my password

Comment: Are you sure the keystore is of the correct application/package?

Comment: Did you generate a keystore already or downloaded (cuz I can see your path is in downloads).

Comment: It's not in my app folder, where should I create the keystore folder in my app package?

Comment: Choose create new and choose your preferred path and select that `.jks` file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [keytool error Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891182/keytool-error-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect)

Comment: if you enter wrong passwords multiple times your keystore may get tampered

Answer (score 0):

```
Cannot load key store: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

its already said that keystore password is incorrect. Maybe because you downloaded it as we can see it was in download path.

Try to Generate Signed APK by clicking the **Create New** and fill up the form. Remember always the Alias and password that you used.

Hope it will help to fix your problem.

[image]