# Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect] still not working

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, glassfish

I've tried everything from the post below:

[keytool error Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891182/keytool-error-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect?newreg=ca45693234a74170ba16718c782d0451)

And it is still not working, I'm still getting an error.

> homecom.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot open file:C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]

I'm using mysql connector java 5.1.45,
glassfish server 4.1,
netbeans as ide

I set the password from changeit to keystore,
I set the connection pool ssl false,
I tried a blank password,
but I'm still getting that error...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you set the connection pool ssl false. I set the useSSL=false and it worked for me. I am using connector/j 5.1.47, glass fish 4.1.1, and NetBeans 8.2

You may want to try the following steps:

1. In the NetBeans IDE, click the Services tab, expand the Servers node, right-click GlassFish Server, and choose View Domain Admin Console. The console will open in a browser.
2. In the console's tree on the left, expand the Resources > JDBC > JDBC Connection Pools nodes, then click your connection pool.
3. In the main window, click the Additional Properties tab.
4. In the URL Value field, modify the url to `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/{yourdbname}?useSSL=false`. This is just an example of mine. You should just add `useSSL=false` after the `{yourdbname}?` in the url.
5. Save the changes. Go back to your NetBeans IDE, right-click the GlassFish Server, and choose Restart.
6. Follow the steps 1-2 agian. This time, in the main window, click the "Ping" button. You sohuld see the "Ping Succeeded" if it works.

Hope this can help.