# Execution failed for task ':app:packageReleaseBundle'

Tags: java, android, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

I have lost key for the beta version migration. I created a new key but am getting this error every time. I tried the solution given in the github solutions related to this. Can anyone tell me why this issue is coming?

I have my key.jks in project\android\app and stored password in key.properties.

What went wrong:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:packageReleaseBundle'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: jarsigner.exefailed with exit code 1 :
  jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16987252/5518027

Comment: I haven't used tomcat server

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution related to flutter with answers given there.. tried to delete gradle.properties, change password to 'changeit' and Android...