# Glassfish and java input in to mysql DB

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, netbeans, glassfish

I have made a user registration for a java web application and there seems to be an issue with glassfish server 4.1.1 and the java SQL driver connecting

I using MySQL java connector 8.0.23 and using the netbeansIDE 8.2RC

code for the connection

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.sql.*;


public class Registerdb 
{
    
    private final String dburl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdb";
    private final String dbuname="root";
    private final String dbpassword="Not4U2no!";
    private final String dbdriver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    
    public void loadDriver(String dbDriver)
    {
        try {
            Class.forName(dbDriver);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public Connection getConnection()
    {
     Connection con=null;
        try {
         con=DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, dbuname, dbpassword);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return con;
    }

    public String insert(member member){
        loadDriver(dbdriver);
        Connection con=getConnection();
        String result ="data enter susccessfully" ;
        String sql="insert into userdb.member values(?,?,?,?)";
        try{
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, member.getUname());
        ps.setString(2, member.getPassword());
        ps.setString(3, member.getEmail());
        ps.setString(4, member.getPhone());
        ps.executeUpdate();
        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            result="data not entered";
        }
       return result; 
    }
    
}
```

the errors

```
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:70)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:833)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:453)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at Registerdb.getConnection(Registerdb.java:41)
    at Registerdb.insert(Registerdb.java:50)
    at register.doPost(register.java:82)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.SSLParamsException: Cannot open file:C:\Users\Kevin Mouko\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2rc\config\GF_4.1.1\domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.getSSLContext(ExportControlled.java:550)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:303)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:188)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:333)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1350)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:157)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:823)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:782)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.getSSLContext(ExportControlled.java:530)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:780)
    ... 52 more
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[register]: Servlet.service() for servlet register threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Registerdb.insert(Registerdb.java:54)
    at register.doPost(register.java:82)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Warning:   The web application [/encore] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   Loading application [encore] at [/encore]
Info:   encore was successfully deployed in 371 milliseconds.
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   Loading application [encore] at [/encore]
Info:   encore was successfully deployed in 393 milliseconds.
Severe:   Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver has automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
Severe:   java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot open file:C:\Users\Kevin Mouko\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2rc\config\GF_4.1.1\domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:70)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:833)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:453)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at Registerdb.getConnection(Registerdb.java:39)
    at Registerdb.insert(Registerdb.java:48)
    at register.doPost(register.java:82)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.SSLParamsException: Cannot open file:C:\Users\Kevin Mouko\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2rc\config\GF_4.1.1\domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.getSSLContext(ExportControlled.java:550)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:303)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:188)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:333)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1350)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:157)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:823)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:782)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.getSSLContext(ExportControlled.java:530)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:780)
    ... 52 more
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[register]: Servlet.service() for servlet register threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Registerdb.insert(Registerdb.java:52)
    at register.doPost(register.java:82)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If any more details are needed please let me know happy to give as much detail as needed

Comment: I think the messages are clear:  *java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed* *Cannot open file:C:\Users\Kevin Mouko\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2rc\config\GF_4.1.1\domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]*

Comment: @Jens i have tried the fix for this from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891182/keytool-error-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect and this did not work. do you have another alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running Application Server, you do not need manage connections manually, just let Server do it for you:
https://www.javaxt.com/wiki/Tutorials/Glassfish/How_to_set_up_a_Connection_Pool

Do not forget to put JDBC drivet to {your domain}/lib directory, put persistence.xml file into resources root: https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-persistence-xml/. Then you may simply inject EntityManager to any EJB or Servlet like:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "your_persistent_unit_name")
private EntityManager em;
```

Then simply invoke

```
em.createNativeQuery("...").executeUpdate();
```

or use any JPA opportunity, you need.