# keytool said "keystore password was incorrect"

Tags: java, ssl, netty, keytool

I use these commands to generate a selfsigned cert:

```
gmssl ecparam -genkey -name sm2p256v1 -out ca.key
gmssl req -new -key ca.key -out ca.csr
gmssl x509 -req -days 3650 -sm3 -signkey ca.key -in ca.csr -out ca.crt

gmssl ecparam -genkey -name sm2p256v1 -out server.key
gmssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
gmssl x509 -req -days 3650 -sm3 -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -in server.csr -out server.crt

gmssl pkcs12 -export -in server.crt -inkey server.key -out server.p12 -name serverkey
```

and I input 123456 whenever it saied a password is need to input.
but when I try to import server cert and key to a jks file, it doesn't work, I also try to replace some of the password into "changeit" but keytool show the same error:

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass 123456 -destkeypass 123456 \
-destkeystore server.jks -srckeystore server.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 \
-srcstorepass 123456 -alias serverkey

keytool error: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
```

#### some addition details:

#### reply to the answer of @dave_thompson_085:

thank you so much for answering my question.

actually, I want to build a netty https server using GMSSL, but I'm not familiar with that and I dont find tutorial about how to build a gmssl server using netty, so I want to build a normal SSL server first and than modify it to GMSSL. The tutorial I find to build a SSL server use a jks file, so I try to put SM2 key and cert into it to modify it to GMSSL.

I also find other way use directly cert and key file, like build a SSLContext through these code:

```
File certChainFile = new File("server.crt");  
File keyFile = new File("server.key");  
File rootFile = new File("ca.crt");  
SslContext sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forServer(certChainFile, keyFile)  
.trustManager(rootFile).protocols("GMSSLv.1.0")  
// will it recognize these string "GMSSLv.1.0"? I'dont konw, I just try.
.clientAuth(ClientAuth.NONE).build();
```

but it throw error when I try to run:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File does not contain valid certificates
```

I search these error on google, someone said i need to using a pkcs8 cert, so I try this command:

```
gmssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform PEM -in server.p12 -out server.p8 -nocrypt
```

and it doesn't work too:

```
unable to load key  
4577107392:error:25066067:DSO support routines:dlfcn_load:could not load the shared library:crypto/dso/dso_dlfcn.c:113:filename(libproviders.dylib): dlopen(libproviders.dylib, 2): image not found  
4577107392:error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:crypto/dso/dso_lib.c:161:  
4577107392:error:0E07506E:configuration file routines:module_load_dso:error loading dso:crypto/conf/conf_mod.c:220:module=providers, path=providers  
4577107392:error:0E076071:configuration file routines:module_run:unknown module name:crypto/conf/conf_mod.c:162:module=providers  
4577107392:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:695:
```

actually I'm very confuse, I don't know how to use netty to build a gmssl server.

do netty support gmssl and SM2 SM3 SM4 algorithm? I see this issue it seem to support(https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/11406), but it seen that the pull request doesnt imply the encryption algorithm.

how should I do to build a GMSSL server? should I use a special version of JCE, Netty or JDK? or I need to imply the protocol by myself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [keytool error Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891182/keytool-error-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect)

Comment: Your modified question is very different and I can't really answer; do you want me to delete my now-inapplicable answer to avoid discouraging others? As I said Bouncy supports the Chinese _primitives_, but neither it nor standard Java supports the apparently modified _protocol_. Netty does support a variant of tomcat-native (i.e. not Java), which interfaces to OpenSSL, and https://github.com/guanzhi/GmSSL says it is compatible with OpenSSL, so that probably works, but I don't know enough about them for an answer. Alternatively, GmSSL says it supports apache, which you could use as a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Meta: this isn't programming, and it's borderline at best for development; it probably would be better suited on security.SX or superuser. But as no one seems to be voting to close, at least not yet ...

**The problem is that 'standard' Java doesn't support SM2,** or more exactly the standard *providers* in Oracle or OpenJDK Java don't. If you run your `keytool` command with `-v` added to get the full stacktrace, you can see `PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad` actually got an exception for `Unknown named curve` but wrapped it as `password was incorrect`, which I call confusing and bad UI on its part.

[BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org) (in reasonably recent versions) does, but I can get keytool to process such a key only by the fairly clumsy means of:

1. specifying `-J-cp -J/path/to/bcprov-jdk15on-$ver.jar`
2. modifying the JRE/conf/security/java.security file to add to the provider list an entry for `org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider` -- or since I prefer not to modify my JRE, modifying a *copy* and using `-J-Djava.security.properties=$filename` to point to it
3. specifying `-srcprovidername BC` AND `-destprovidername BC`

and moreover, this won't put the result in a JKS file, because the Bouncy provider doesn't support JKS. Why do you want JKS anyway? All versions of Java that are still supported can read PKCS12 -- but for SM2 only if using the Bouncy provider, so you'll need that in your application(s) and/or their JVM(s). And you'll need the Bouncy provider anyway to do anything at all with the key once you've read it in -- and maybe the cert also, I'm not sure exactly when that gets parsed.