# java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot open file:keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, glassfish

I am new to Java world, while creating a webapp using NetBeans code is working fine till get method is executed but when I am trying to execute the SQL query glassfish is unable to show data from MSQL DB and giving errors. I am using

- Apache NetBeans IDE 18
- JDK20
- Glassfish 7.0.3
- MySQL 8.0 CE
- windows10

In my project created a servlet called GreetingServlet.java which should get executed to fetch data from library database. library is running. But my code is showing errors in web browser like

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
type Exception report
messageInternal Server Error
descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Servlet Could not display records.
root cause

java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot open file:C:\Users\Subhranshu\glassfish7\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
root cause

com.mysql.cj.exceptions.SSLParamsException: Cannot open file:C:\Users\Subhranshu\glassfish7\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
root cause

java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
root cause

java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
```

Please find my code:

```java
Connection con;
con = null;  
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    con =DriverManager.getConnection 
    //("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/library","root","");
    ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library","root","");
    stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from users where username = ? and password = ?");
    stmt.setString(1, username);
    stmt.setString(2, password);
    rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891182/keytool-error-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect) maybe help?

Answer (score 2):

The MySQL driver uses secure connection (SSL/TLS) by default, which doesn't work out of the box and requires some configuration in GlassFish.

If you're just getting started, I recommend to disable SSL in the driver, with this connection URL:

"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library?useSSL=false"

Comment: Just for reference, if you'd like to use SSL, you need to specify the following property in the JVM config: `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit`, where "changeit" is the default password for the GlassFish certificte stores, and you'll also need to add the public key from the MySQL server into GlassFish so that it's trusted by GlassFish. But you only need to do this in production if you want to secure the communication between GlassFish and MySQL.

Comment: You'll need to add the *certificate* from the MySQL server into Glassfish's truststore, if it isn't signed by a CA.

Comment: Yes, I’m sorry, I meant the certificate, not the public key.