# How do I use client certificates in a client java application?

Tags: java, https, certificate, keystore

This is a topic that has taken me quite some time to figure out. There are bits and pieces of information scattered and one has to put everything together. I was hoping that with this post I could help others quickly assemble a working solution.

---

I have a `client-cert.pem`, `client-key.pem` and a `root.pem` files and I need to used them in my Java client to access a remote REST API.

How do I package them into a truststore and use them to make API calls?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to load your certificates into your application your will need to package them into a truststore.

**Creating a truststore**

given the 3 files:

- `client-cert.pem`
- `client-key.pem`
- `root.pem`

Run the following commands in your terminal. Replace `PASSWORD` with your desired password.

1. Package your client key and certificate into a keystore. This will create a PKCS12 keystore file.

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -export \
       -inkey client-key.pem -in client-cert.pem \
       -out client.pfx -passout pass:PASSWORD \
       -name qlikClient
   ```
2. Add the keystore to your truststore. It will create a truststore if the destination doesn't exit. This will create a `PKCS12` truststore file. By default it creates a `JKS` file which is a proprietary format. By specifying `-deststoretype PKCS12` you will create a file which is in an industry standard format.

   ```
   keytool -importkeystore \
       -destkeystore truststore.pfx -deststoretype PKCS12 -deststorepass PASSWORD \
       -srckeystore client.pfx -srcstorepass PASSWORD -srcstoretype PKCS12 \
       -alias qlikClient
   ```
3. Add your root CA to the truststore

   ```
   keytool -importcert \
       -keystore truststore.pfx -storepass PASSWORD \
       -file root.pem -noprompt \
       -alias qlikServerCACert
   ```

*Note that in the above commands we use the same `PASSWORD` for both the keystore and the truststore. You could alternatively use different passwords. Also note that you have to specify an alias for each item you add to the truststore.*

If you want your truststore to trust all cacerts available in your system add `-trustcacerts` option to step 2 or 3.

You can use the following command to list the contents of your truststore

```
keytool -list -keystore truststore.pfx -storepass PASSWORD
```

**Using the truststore in you application**

Once you have your truststore you need to load it into your application. Assuming you have a constant `KEYSTORE_PATH` holding the path to your truststore and `keyStorePass` holding the password, read the truststore file into a `KeyStore`

```
private KeyStore readStore() {
  try (InputStream keyStoreStream = new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE_PATH)) {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12"); // or "JKS"
    keyStore.load(keyStoreStream, keyStorePass.toCharArray());
    return keyStore;
  } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}
```

Create a custom `SSLContext` and a custom `HttpClient`,

```
final KeyStore truststore = readStore();

final SSLContext sslContext;
try {
  sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
      .loadTrustMaterial(truststore, new TrustAllStrategy())
      .loadKeyMaterial(truststore, keyStorePass.toCharArray(), (aliases, socket) -> "qlikClient")
      .build();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException | KeyManagementException | UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Failed to read keystore", e);
}
final CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext).build();
```

You can now use this `HttpClient` to make requests to your API.

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet("https://sense-gcp-central1eu.net:4242/qrs/app/full"));
```

Or, if you are using the [OpenUnirest/unirest-java](https://github.com/OpenUnirest/unirest-java) library, you can configure Unirest to use your custom `HttpClient`

```
Unirest.config().httpClient(httpClient);
HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get("https://sense-gcp-central1eu.net:4242/qrs/app/full").asJson();
```

**References**

- https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-keytool-keystore-certificate-tutorials
- [How do I use an SSL client certificate with Apache HttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223084/how-do-i-use-an-ssl-client-certificate-with-apache-httpclient)

Comment: You can also use `-Djavax.net.debug=all` to troubleshoot issues with the SSL certificates in your requests. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html

Comment: this was very useful. One minor detail, is that you might also need add xref header and query parameter https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/February2020/Subsystems/RepositoryServiceAPI/Content/Sense_RepositoryServiceAPI/RepositoryServiceAPI-Connect-API-Using-Xrfkey-Headers.htm , or else you can get a somewhat generic looking error, that I first thought was to do with SSL config

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question, but I figured out something wrong in your question.
The truststore is used by your client to list the remote server to which it can trust.
If the certificate/key you have and would like to use, is for your own java client, you should include them in your keystore, not truststore.
This is the store your client will use in case the remote server asks your client to authenticate itself.

On top of the already given answers, if you are using spring boot and resttemplate as http client implementation, you can use the keystore you created by doing so in your application properties:

```
server:
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-alias: <<app-client-alias>>
    key-store: <<path_to_your_keystore>>
    key-store-password: <<PASSWORD>>
```