# How to running request Http Client with Cer and key File (SSL)- Java?

Tags: java, keystore

I saw that there were already questions about converting files to Java KeyStore,

But I can not find any **clear answer** on what needs to be run a rest API request from Java code.

I think it will really help everyone if there is a clear answer - step by step because this issue is not really clear.
thanks.

Comment: How about you add the parts which steps you think are already clear and which might need improvement. You could altough link the anwers you find useful on this topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223084/how-do-i-use-an-ssl-client-certificate-with-apache-httpclient

Comment: @Prasann, The link you brought has only references for the code but it is very difficult to understand what needs to be done with the files (cer, key)

Comment: @Prasann, (I will try to build a clear answer based on your link, if I can maybe add it there and delete the question), but I still think it would be helpful if there is a detailed explanation here step by step.
In addition, I see that more people have done up vote probably this is important, thx

Comment: @GavrielCohen, `.cer` is a certificate and `.jks` is a keystore. Look at https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-a-jks-and-a-cer-certificate-file-Is-it-possible-to-convert-from-one-to-the-other to understand the difference between the two. While invoking a service over SSL, you have 2 options. 1) Use a JKS file o explicily specify the certificate to use or 2) Add the certificate in cacerts and invoke the service normally without needing o specify the certificate. `cacerts` is the java truststore

Comment: @Prasann, Thank you on your comment