# Why I can't retrieve this file when I run the .jar version of my Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, java-resources

I am working on a Spring Batch application and I am finding some problem retrieving an SSL certificate file (used from **RestTemplate**) when I execute the **.jar** file containing my application. My application works fine if I run it from STS (Eclipse).

I will try to explain in details what I have done and what is the problem. Into this folder of my project **/src/main/resources/static** I have put my certificate file named **certificate.pfx**:

[image]

Then into my code I declaring this method returning a **RestTemplate** bean that retrieve and use this certificate file in order to perform REST call to an external API:

```
@Bean
RestTemplate restTemplate() throws KeyManagementException, UnrecoverableKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
    final String password = "password";
    //final String pfxPath = "/home/andrea/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.11.0.RELEASE/UpdateInfoBatch/target/classes/static/certificate.pfx";
    
    
    URL clientCertRes = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("static/certificate.pfx");
    
    
    File clientCertFileile = Paths.get(clientCertRes.toURI()).toFile();
    
    
    String clientCertFileileAbsolutePath = clientCertFileile.getAbsolutePath();
    
    System.out.println("clientCertFileileAbsolutePath: " + clientCertFileileAbsolutePath);  
    
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory = getHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(clientCertFileileAbsolutePath,password);
    
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory);
    
    return restTemplate;
    
}
```

If I execute my code from STS\Eclipse it works fine: I have no exception and the call to my external API correctly uses the needed certificate.

The problem is that when I try to perform my application executing the compiled **.jar** file version. Infact if I execute:

```
java -jar UpdateInfoBatch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I am obtaining the following exception starting the application context:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-08-24 19:04:37.115 ERROR 6544 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springBatchExampleJobLauncher' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/andrea/git/notartel-api-batch/target/UpdateInfoBatch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/notariato/updateInfo/SpringBatchExampleJobLauncher.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'updateInfoBatchConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'notaryListServiceAdapter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'notaryListServiceAdapter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'notaryService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'notaryService' defined in class path resource [com/notariato/updateInfo/config/BeanConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.notariato.service.NotaryService]: Factory method 'notaryService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/notariato/updateInfo/config/BeanConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Factory method 'restTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar!/:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar!/:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar!/:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar!/:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar!/:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar!/:2.5.3]
    at com.notariato.updateInfo.UpdateInfoBatchApplication.main(UpdateInfoBatchApplication.java:35) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[UpdateInfoBatch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[UpdateInfoBatch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[UpdateInfoBatch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[UpdateInfoBatch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'updateInfoBatchConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'notaryListServiceAdapter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'notaryListServiceAdapter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'notaryService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'notaryService' defined in class path resource [com/notariato/updateInfo/config/BeanConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.notariato.service.NotaryService]: Factory method 'notaryService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/notariato/updateInfo/config/BeanConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Factory method 'restTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:410) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'notaryListServiceAdapter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'notaryService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'notaryService' defined in class path resource [com/notariato/updateInfo/config/BeanConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.notariato.service.NotaryService]: Factory method 'notaryService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/notariato/updateInfo/config/BeanConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Factory method 'restTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'notaryService' defined in class path resource [com/notariato/updateInfo/config/BeanConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.notariato.service.NotaryService]: Factory method 'notaryService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/notariato/updateInfo/config/BeanConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Factory method 'restTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    ... 65 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.notariato.service.NotaryService]: Factory method 'notaryService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/notariato/updateInfo/config/BeanConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Factory method 'restTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    ... 78 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/notariato/updateInfo/config/BeanConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Factory method 'restTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:362) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:334) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at com.notariato.updateInfo.config.BeanConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e4e5b284.restTemplate(<generated>) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.notariato.updateInfo.config.BeanConfig.notaryService(BeanConfig.java:34) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.notariato.updateInfo.config.BeanConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e4e5b284.CGLIB$notaryService$1(<generated>) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.notariato.updateInfo.config.BeanConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e4e5b284$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3144f839.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at com.notariato.updateInfo.config.BeanConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e4e5b284.notaryService(<generated>) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    ... 79 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Factory method 'restTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    ... 102 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: null
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:156) ~[jdk.zipfs:na]
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getPath(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:142) ~[jdk.zipfs:na]
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:208) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:98) ~[na:na]
    at com.notariato.updateInfo.config.BeanConfig.restTemplate(BeanConfig.java:47) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.notariato.updateInfo.config.BeanConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e4e5b284.CGLIB$restTemplate$0(<generated>) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.notariato.updateInfo.config.BeanConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e4e5b284$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3144f839.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at com.notariato.updateInfo.config.BeanConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e4e5b284.restTemplate(<generated>) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    ... 103 common frames omitted
```

As you can see in the previous stacktrace the cause of this exception is this one:

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: null
```

and I am pretty sure that it should be related to these lines of code where I retrieve the certificate file:

```
URL clientCertRes = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("static/certificate.pfx");
File clientCertFileile = Paths.get(clientCertRes.toURI()).toFile();
String clientCertFileileAbsolutePath = clientCertFileile.getAbsolutePath();
```

I am pretty sure because I tried to delete all the lines related to obtain certificate file and I simply returned a classic RestTemplate object:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
```

doing in this way I obtain no more the previous exception (but instead I obtain the expected SSL exception because to perform my call I need this certificate).

So...what is wrong? what am I missing? How can I try to fix this issue?

What could be a good solution?

1. To embed the certificate directly into the **.jar** file? (in this case I will have an all in one solution)
2. To point to a specific directory of my file system where I will put my certificate? (maybe it could be better because if in the future the certificate will change I can simply replace it into the file system avoiding to recompile and redeploy my application)

What do you think about?

Comment: Did you try to pass path as "classpath:/static/certificate.pfx" ?

Comment: Show your `getHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` method

Comment: Does this solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399422/read-file-from-resources-folder-in-spring-boot ?

Answer (score 0):

Code in this answer is a guess because I do not know what is inside the `getHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` :). But I think, you can solve the problem as follows:

1. Change the way you supply certificate from plain `File` to `URL`
2. Use `ClassPathResource` to get the certificate's `URL`

##### 1. Supply certificate using `URL`

I guess you're using custom `SSLContext` created using the `SSLContexts.custom()` returned builder, something similar to:

```java
SSLContexts.custom()
        .loadTrustMaterial(new File("/tmp/fred.zip"), "apples".toCharArray())
        .build();
```

You can use the overload accepting `URL` instead:

```
SSLContexts.custom()
        .loadTrustMaterial(new URL("...."), "apples".toCharArray())
        .build();
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45541092/6486622) answer

##### 2. Use `ClassPathResource` to obtain `URL`

For example:

```
ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("/fred.pfx", SpringBootResourcesApplication.class);
URL url = resource.getURL();
```

- `fred.pfx` is the file I'm loading. It is placed directly in `resources` directory
- `SpringBootResourcesApplication.class` is the class that loads the file

This will work in IDE and in jar file

##### Wiring everything together

```java
public class SpringBootResourcesApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("/fred.pfx", SpringBootResourcesApplication.class);
        URL url = resource.getURL();

        System.out.println(url);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
                .loadTrustMaterial(url, "apples".toCharArray())
                .build();
        System.out.println(sslContext);
    }
}
```

- The output from IDE:

  ```
  file:/home/caco3/IdeaProjects/spring-boot-resources/target/classes/fred.pfx
  javax.net.ssl.SSLContext@217ed35e
  ```
- From jar:

  ```
  jar:file:/home/caco3/IdeaProjects/spring-boot-resources/target/spring-boot-resources-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/fred.pfx
  javax.net.ssl.SSLContext@3444d69d
  ```

##### Why `java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException` thrown

`Path.get` does not always succeed.
When you get a `URL` for the `Path` using code similar to:

```java
URL resource = SpringBootResourcesApplication.class.getClassLoader().getResource("application.properties");
```

The result can be different, for example:

- From IDE *in my case* it is:

  ```
  file:/home/caco3/IdeaProjects/spring-boot-resources/target/classes/application.properties
  ```
- From *jar*:

  ```
  jar:file:/home/caco3/IdeaProjects/spring-boot-resources/target/spring-boot-resources-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/application.properties
  ```

These `URI`s are handled differently:

- The `file:/...` `URI` can be successfully converted to a `Path`
- But the `jar:file:/...` cannot: it requires an explicit `FileSystem` to be created

That's why the exception was thrown