# Is it right to add server certs and client certs with key to same keystore and provide it to the Java program using "javax.net.ssl.keyStore"

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, mtls

First I created my client JKS file using below commands:

Adding the server certs:

```
keytool -import -alias <server cert alias> -file <server cert> -keystore <jks file>
```

Adding the Client cert with Key:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -file <client certificate pem> -keypass <client key pass> -storepass <truststore pass> -keystore <jks file>
```

then added the code just like proposed here:
[How do I use an SSL client certificate with Apache HttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223084/how-do-i-use-an-ssl-client-certificate-with-apache-httpclient)

The SSL connection protocol here is mTLS and that is why I need to add the client certificates so that client certificate can be verified by the server during the handshake.

When I am trying to call the REST API I get following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

From the suggested link I am trying to execute below code:

```
    private static final String KEYSTOREPATH = "keystore.jks";
    private static final String KEYSTOREPASS = "keystorepass";
    private static final String KEYPASS = "keypass";

    KeyStore readStore() throws Exception {
        try (InputStream keyStoreStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(KEYSTOREPATH)) {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            keyStore.load(keyStoreStream, KEYSTOREPASS.toCharArray());
            return keyStore;    
       }
    }

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadKeyMaterial(readStore(), KEYPASS.toCharArray()).build();
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext).build();
    HttpPost postReq = new HttpPost("REST API URL");
    <set payload>
    <set headers>
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postReq);
    assertEquals(200, response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
    EntityUtils.consume(entity);
```

Comment: No. The server certificate goes in the server’s key store and the client’s truststore, and the client certificate goes in the client’s key store and the server’s truststore. Don’t conflate these entities. They have different purposes and different security regimes.

Comment: You did NOT 'add client cert with key'. `keytool -import` CANNOT import a key. But your current problem is happening before client-auth is even attempted and is with the truststore not the keystore -- if the server's CA is not well-known, as apparently it isn't, you need to load (a file containing) either the server cert or better the server's _CA_ cert, as `loadTrustMaterial` or equivalent.

Comment: What currently is happening is that no trust path can be build for the server authentication. That likely happens because of the following reasons: 1. the (root) CA certificate is not trusted or 2. the other party is lazy and doesn't send the full chain (possibly excluding root) to you, and one or more intermediate CA certificates cannot be found.

Comment: (but yes, you'd need `loadTrustMaterial` for this, likely the trust store is currently not configured at all; it'll just use the default `cacerts` file, and in the end you'll need *both* methods even if you'd use the same store).