# Spring Tool Suite can't connect to Update site using SSL (HTTPS)

Tags: spring, ssl, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

When try to connect to update sites under help->Install New Software I get:

Unable to read repository at https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.4/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.4/content.xml.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I have tried to import the certificate into the truststore as well as set it in the sts.ini file but to no avail.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I tried this update site just now with STS 3.6.2 release candidate: https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.4 and it seems to work for me. Probably the problem is something in your specific network environment.

Comment: I don't realy know what to do about your problem, but seems other people have run into something similar outside STS context. Maybe some of their answers might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908948/java-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find

Comment: Commenting out the -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore* (which I added some days ago in order to solve JIRA connection problems) inside of STS.ini worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue while trying to add templates to STS (3.6.2). The issue was my organization's usage of an SSL inspection tool that presents its certificate instead of the real one (GitHub.com).

The solution was to export the SSL inspection's certificate (using IE for example) and add it to the cacerts file. Use [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/rstep2.html) for the procedure.

Then update the [sts.ini file and add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712417/how-to-configure-truststore-for-javax-net-ssl-truststore-on-windows) the following lines:

-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\security\cacerts
-Djava.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit

Finally - restart STS.