# Zimbra mail server - how to create authentication certificate for zimbra mail server

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, mail-server, starttls

This is the first time i am posting a question on this portal.I have zimbra mail server domain name and port-587. it is giving the following exception when i am trying to create certificate.

```
package com.test;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
 
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLException;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
 
public class InstallCert {
 
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String host;
        int port;
        char[] passphrase;
        if ((args.length == 1) || (args.length == 2)) {
            final String[] c = args[0].split(":");
            host = c[0];
            port = (c.length == 1) ? 443 : Integer.parseInt(c[1]);
            final String p = (args.length == 1) ? "changeit" : args[1];
            passphrase = p.toCharArray();
        } else {
            host = "mail.clientname.com";
            port = 587;
            final String p= "changeit"; 
            passphrase = p.toCharArray();
            System.out.println(
                    "Usage: java InstallCert <host>[:port] [passphrase]");
           // return;
        }
 
        File file = new File("jssecacerts");
        if (file.isFile() == false) {
            final char SEP = File.separatorChar;
            final File dir = new File(System.getProperty("java.home")
                    + SEP + "lib" + SEP + "security");
            file = new File(dir, "jssecacerts");
            if (file.isFile() == false) {
                file = new File(dir, "cacerts");
            }
        }
 
        System.out.println("Loading KeyStore " + file + "...");
        final InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        final KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(in, passphrase);
        in.close();
 
        final SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        final TrustManagerFactory tmf =
                TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory
                        .getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(ks);
        final X509TrustManager defaultTrustManager =
                (X509TrustManager) tmf.getTrustManagers()[0];
        final SavingTrustManager tm = new SavingTrustManager(
                defaultTrustManager);
        context.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
        final SSLSocketFactory factory = context.getSocketFactory();
 
        System.out.println("Opening connection to "
                + host + ":" + port + "...");
        final SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(host, port);
        socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
        try {
            System.out.println("Starting SSL handshake...");
            socket.startHandshake();
            socket.close();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("No errors, certificate is already trusted");
        } catch (final SSLException e) {
            System.out.println("palu");
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
 
        final X509Certificate[] chain = tm.chain;
        if (chain == null) {
            System.out.println("Could not obtain server certificate chain");
            return;
        }
 
        final BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Server sent " + chain.length + " certificate(s):");
        System.out.println();
        final MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        final MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        for (int i = 0; i < chain.length; i++) {
            final X509Certificate cert = chain[i];
            System.out.println(" " + (i + 1) + " Subject "
                    + cert.getSubjectDN());
            System.out.println("   Issuer  " + cert.getIssuerDN());
            sha1.update(cert.getEncoded());
            System.out.println("   sha1    " + toHexString(sha1.digest()));
            md5.update(cert.getEncoded());
            System.out.println("   md5     " + toHexString(md5.digest()));
            System.out.println();
        }
 
        System.out.println("Enter certificate to add to trusted keystore"
                + " or 'q' to quit: [1]");
        final String line = reader.readLine().trim();
        int k;
        try {
            k = (line.length() == 0) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(line) - 1;
        } catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("KeyStore not changed");
            return;
        }
 
        final X509Certificate cert = chain[k];
        final String alias = host + "-" + (k + 1);
        ks.setCertificateEntry(alias, cert);
 
        final OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ks.store(out, passphrase);
        out.close();
 
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(cert);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(
                "Added certificate to keystore 'cacerts' using alias '"
                        + alias + "'");
    }
 
    private static final char[] HEXDIGITS = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();
 
    private static String toHexString(final byte[] bytes) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 3);
        for (int b : bytes) {
            b &= 0xff;
            sb.append(HEXDIGITS[b >> 4]);
            sb.append(HEXDIGITS[b & 15]);
            sb.append(' ');
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
 
    private static class SavingTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
 
        private final X509TrustManager tm;
        private X509Certificate[] chain;
 
        SavingTrustManager(final X509TrustManager tm) {
            this.tm = tm;
        }
 
        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new X509Certificate[0];
            // throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
 
        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain,
                final String authType)
                throws CertificateException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
 
        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain,
                final String authType)
                throws CertificateException {
            this.chain = chain;
            this.tm.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
        }
    }
}
```

while executing it is giving the following exception----

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:671)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:504)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at com.test.InstallCert.main(InstallCert.java:81)
Could not obtain server certificate chain
```

please see [this link](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/)

i have got code from the [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908948/java-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find)

Answer (score 0):

Single server or multi server? single domain or multi domain? self signed or commerical cert?

It is due to the fact that you are talking to an HTTP server, not an HTTPS server. Did you use the correct port number for HTTPS?

Comment: Thanks khondhu for ur reply.  actually my clint want to send email to its customer using its companies domain name . for which that they are using zimbra server. they have provided us some php files and through we are able to send mail but as a standalne application.so main issue is that i dont know how to use them in my web app(java/j2ee). for other client i am using noreply@mycompdomain.com. if u want more information i can provide to you.

Comment: So, you are using this "php mail application" as your client, and the server in question is a zimbra server to which you get the above SSL exception.

Have you attempted communication via SMTP port 25?

You have not provided enought information in the opening question for anyone to able to assist you here.

Comment: Actually my client install Zimbra mail server on their server and we are using mail api in our Bi tools to send mail to client's customer as noreply@mycompanyname.com as sender name. Here we are smtp provided by Gmail. But now they want to send mail using Zimbra server and with its companies name as domain name. They have install Zimbra mail server on their server and given domain name, emailid and port to configure it. As of now I don't have much idea how to configure it. So first I tried by using Java code then php but unable to do anything. Please help and let me come out from this mess.