# SSL: how to get access to HTTPS in docker container

Tags: ssl, docker

I'm not very familiar with SSL certificates/handshakes and I have a big problem now.

I want to get access to an URL https://myhost:443/ inside a docker container. The URL is defined in apache virtualhost, and it's using HTTPS with a certificate httpd.crt:

```
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/certs/httpd.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/private/httpd.key
```

But when I try to get access to https://myhost:443/api inside a docker container, I get this:

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Basically I have no right to make SSL connection because I do not have certificate in the container.

My problem is, how to make the HTTPS connection work? Do I need to put the same certificate(httpd.crt) inside the container? Where should I put it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908948/java-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find), I would say you have 2 ways:

1. You could create a docker image with the `JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts` file edited with the certificated added.
2. Or, if security is not that important in this case, you could pass java vm some parameters on the container creation `docker run -e JAVA_OPTS='-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore' <image-name>`. I took this from [here](https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/issues/8).

Hope this helps.