# How to make enable https in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I want connect url host with HTTPS.
-Does codename one allow to connect url with https ?
-If allow then can you please provide some code hint for same ?
-How to generate certificate for https(Security) in codename one?
 Can you please let me know how to resolve it. My application needs to be supported on all platforms (Andriod, IOS, windows) and I don't want to write native code for all platforms separately.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing is to set the URL with 'https'. Thats all, for debugging you need to do some more steps which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38970049/1552410) on SO.

f.e.

```
ConnectionRequest request = new ConnectionRequest();
request.setUrl("https://....");
```

Comment: i changed the Answer