# Soap request over Https in java using client stub

Tags: java, soap

I am having issues sending a soap request over https using client stub.
I am running ubuntu 16 and using eclipse. Ive added the certificate in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib` using keytool.

Any help would be gladly appreciated.

> Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>       at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
>       at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
>       at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
>       at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
>       at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
>       at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
>       at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
>       ... 41 more
>   Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>       at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
>       at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
>       at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
>       at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
>       ... 47 more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908948/java-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find)

Comment: Still having issues, I ran the application with -Djavax.net.debug=SSL enabled and the response Im getting is: main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown

Answer (score 0):

Use below JVM arguments in your tomcat or application server, it should work

```
-Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\client.pfx
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=xxxxx
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyPassword=xxxxx
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\keystore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=xxxxxx
```