# ERROR: SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

Need help. Recently our rundeck server  is running on HTTP and change it to HTTPS and one of the Java based application is connecting to it. When I change the properties on the Java Application to HTTPS it gives me a error

```
 [ERROR] HttpJobFactory - Error encountered while processing request
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1914)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:279)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:273)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1472)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:213)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:913)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:849)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1033)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1342)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1369)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1353)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
```

Tho, I already added the rundeck certificate under /usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/security/cacerts .

This is the syntax I used;

```
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias <your domain> -file ~/<your domain>.crt -keystore <JAVA HOME>/jre/lib/security/cacerts -keypass changeit -storepass changeit
```

My reference :[Resolving javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore)

Comment: With little information you provided it is too many possible reasons.Please run your program with option -Djavax.net.debug=all and add output to question (if it is possible, it may disclose some info about your system). How to understand output: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html

Comment: might be useful (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908948/java-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED THE PROBLEM!! By adding all lets'encrypt certificate and cross signed it