# sbt failing to start up with sun certificate errors on mac

Tags: scala, plugins, jvm, sbt, certificate

When i try to start my sbt, it fails with certain errors which prevents startup. I'm not behind corporate firewall. This is on a mac.

> [error] Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/ivys/ivy.xml
>   [error] Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/ivys/ivy.xml
>   [error] Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://artifactory.dkandu.me/artifactory/repo/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/sbt-0.13.17.pom
>   [error] Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://artifactory.dkandu.me/artifactory/sbt-plugins/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/ivys/ivy.xml

Looked up lot of links for workaround, but couldn't get it to work. Has anyone solved these issues successfully in the past?

Comment: I moved my comment to an answer because of formatting.

Answer (score 0):

this helped me:

- [Java: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908948/java-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Especially these two answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12146838/2750966
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31133183/2750966