# Making a HTTPS request without certificates doesn't work on desktop

Tags: java, rest, https, postman

I have to access a Https API. It **works** just fine with **Postman** and with the [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) library.

But when I try it on a desktop java application it just says:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target      com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

My non-working desktop code:

```
HttpURLConnection con;
            String response;
            try {
                con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(LOGIN_URL).openConnection();
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream(); //throws error
                os.flush();
                return "200";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }
```

My Android working code:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            RequestParams rp = new RequestParams();
            client.get("LOGIN_URL", rp, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
                    
                    return new String(response); //works
                }

            });
```

So, my question here is: If it is possible to make it run on Android, why is not working with **Apache HttpComponents** or the **HttpURLConnection** methods?

Is there any library I can use **without installing any certificates** which works just like on Android? I just want to trust the web service without it for several reasons.

Comment: Show how you try it by yourself. Maybe piece of code. Your requested URL works fine even in browser. Probably you just send a request wrong. Postman doesn't add any certificates by default (you can look in settings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add the root chain to your CA certificates file so java can verify the self-signed certificates.

Postman trusts certificates that you have explicitly trusted in your browser.

To update your CA certs file, you'll need to locate it, as you've probably got the JDK installed the one you're looking for will most likely be in the JRE folder of your JDK. `./jdk1.8/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

To add a certificate to your trust store use `keytool` if java is on your environment path start by running this command where example.der is your certificate. I'd encourage you to give it a better alias name as well.

`keytool -import -alias example -keystore  /path/to/cacerts -file example.der`

You'll be prompted for a password javas default is `changeit` enter the password and enter `yes` when asked if you trust the certificate.

After adding the certificate you can use keytool again to list all the certificates you have in your keystore, again you'll be prompted for a password.

`keytool -list -v -keystore /path/to/cacerts`

When I ran this command I was given a list; you should be able to find a certificate with an alias name of `example`. This one happened to the be first in my list.

```
Alias name: digicertglobalrootca [jdk]
Creation date: 26 Aug. 2016
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=DigiCert Global Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
Issuer: CN=DigiCert Global Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
Serial number: 83be056904246b1a1756ac95991c74a
Valid from: Fri Nov 10 10:00:00 AEST 2006 until: Mon Nov 10 10:00:00 AEST 2031
Certificate fingerprints:
     SHA1: A8:98:5D:3A:65:E5:E5:C4:B2:D7:D6:6D:40:C6:DD:2F:B1:9C:54:36
     SHA256: 43:48:A0:E9:44:4C:78:CB:26:5E:05:8D:5E:89:44:B4:D8:4F:96:62:BD:26:DB:25:7F:89:34:A4:43:C7:01:61
Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3
```

You've updated your question to include that you want to ignore certificates...

> Please don't ignore certificate errors. Deal with them instead.
>   Ignoring certificate errors opens the connection to potential MITM
>   attacks. It's tempting to say it's only for test code, it won't end up in
>   production, but we all know what happens when the deadline approaches:
>   the code doesn't show any error when tested -> we can ship
>   it as it is.

Now I know you're determined to do this ANYWAY - so [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20121022013056/http://exampledepot.com/egs/javax.net.ssl/TrustAll.html) is some relevant code.

```
// Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
    new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
        public void checkClientTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
        public void checkServerTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
    }
};

// Install the all-trusting trust manager
try {
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
} catch (Exception e) {
}

// Now you can access an https URL without having the certificate in the truststore
try {
    URL url = new URL("https://hostname/index.html");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
}
```

Comment: But ill need to do that in every computer I intall my client. There's nothing that works just like the Android Asynchronous Http Client but on desktop?

Comment: You have a few options you can Add the option "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=..." to the command that boots your client application and include the cacerts file you've created with your application

Comment: That worked really well, thank you very much. I will ask for the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because Postman trusts certificates that you have explicitly said you've trusted browsing, but Java doesn't.

Try with this [solution to the SSLHandshakeException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12146838/5133329):

> The problem appears when your server has self signed certificate. To
>   workaround it you can add this certificate to the list of trusted
>   certificates of your JVM.
>
> In [this
>   article](http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/ssl/pkix_path_building_failed.html)
>   author describes how to fetch the certificate from your browser and
>   add it to cacerts file of your JVM. You can either edit
>   JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts file or run you application with
>   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore parameter. Verify which JDK/JRE you are using too as this is often a source of confusion.
>
> See also: [How are SSL certificate server names resolved/Can I add
>   alternative names using
>   keytool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443081/how-are-ssl-certificate-server-names-resolved-can-i-add-alternative-names-using)
>   If you run into java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name
>   matching localhost found exception.

Comment: I just noticed it's not only Postman, It also happens with the Android Asynchronous Http Client library.
Unlikely, it only works on Android and I need this to work on desktop java.

Comment: Have you tried adding the cert to the JVM trusted certs? I had exactly the same problem and it solved doing it.