# Stackdriver Monitoring API throwing an error while getting time series metrics data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm getting the error

> unable to find valid certification path

from this piece of code:

```
MetricServiceClient mServiceClient = MetricServiceClient.create()
ListTimeSeriesResponse response = mServiceClient.listTimeSeriesCallable().call(request);
```

Error's stack trace:

```
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
```

> ```
>     ... 3 more
>     Suppressed: com.google.api.gax.rpc.AsyncTaskException: Asynchronous task failed
>             at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:57)
>             at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:112)
>             at com.vmware.adapter3.gcp.builder.GoogleCloudMonitoringManager$MetricsCollector.lambda$null$6(GoogleCloudMonitoringManager.java:235)
>             at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
>             at com.vmware.adapter3.gcp.builder.GoogleCloudMonitoringManager$MetricsCollector.lambda$call$7(GoogleCloudMonitoringManager.java:207)
>             at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
>             at com.vmware.adapter3.gcp.builder.GoogleCloudMonitoringManager$MetricsCollector.call(GoogleCloudMonitoringManager.java:194)
>             at com.vmware.adapter3.gcp.builder.GoogleCloudMonitoringManager$MetricsCollector.call(GoogleCloudMonitoringManager.java:165)
>             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>             at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>             ... 3 more Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception Channel Pipeline: [SslHandler#0,
> ```
>
> ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler#0,
>   WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0,
>   DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
>           at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
>           ... 24 more Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General OpenSslEngine problem
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.handshakeException(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1728)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.wrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:770)
>           at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:509)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrap(SslHandler.java:1043)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapNonAppData(SslHandler.java:934)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1392)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1224)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1271)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:505)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:444)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:283)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:931)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:700)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:635)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:552)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:514)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1044)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
>           ... 1 more Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>           at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
>           at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
>           at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
>           at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
>           at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:281)
>           at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslTlsv13X509ExtendedTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(OpenSslTlsv13X509ExtendedTrustManager.java:221)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext$ExtendedTrustManagerVerifyCallback.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext.java:248)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext$AbstractCertificateVerifier.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:699)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSL.readFromSSL(Native
>   Method)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.readPlaintextData(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:589)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1172)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1289)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$1.unwrap(SslHandler.java:199)
>           at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1329)
>           ... 21 more Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>           at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
>           at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
>           at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
>           at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
>           ... 35 more

Which certificate do I need to add? I am not seeing any API to add certificate in Google API. Am I missing anything, or is there any dependent `JAR` issue?

Comment: the same issue was opened by you here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59766881/how-to-call-google-timeseries-minitoring-api-with-sslsocket-factory please refrain from opening duplicate posts, as it makes it harder to help you.

Comment: are you running this on app engine? or in a compute engine instance or else? maybe this post helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12146838/11135166

Comment: This is running outside of the GCP environment, I am trying to fetch the performance metric of a given gcp environment using GCP client jar.

Comment: This is running outside of the GCP environment, I am trying to fetch the performance metric of a given GCP environment using GCP client jar. I have already tried these steps for url monitoring.googleapis.com:443. It is not working. I am looking for some API to set custom trust or SSL or withSslSocketFactory while creating credentials. I am stuck here, please help me