# Hоw to convert website to .txt file for finding in this file some word?

Tags: java

Hоw to convert website to .txt file for finding in this file some word (ex. "Абрамов Николай Викторович")? My code read only html. In other words I want to re-check website every second. If my word appears ( by the author of the website), then my code print "Yes".

And how can I make a computer application to test any other word?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class web {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (;;) {
            try {
                // Create a URL for the desired page
                URL url = new URL("http://abit.itmo.ru/page/195");
                // Read all the text returned by the server
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                String str = null;
                while (in.readLine() != null) {
                    str = in.readLine().toString();
                    System.out.println(str);
                    // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline character(s)
                }
                in.close();
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Абрамов Николай Викторович");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
                if (m.find()) {
                    System.out.println("Yes");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert it to TXT.
If you want just to search for the word you can check it directly . But be careful it can appears as DDOS attack if the period is too short and you may be blocked

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {

   public  static  String wordToFind = "30 Day";
    public  static  String siteURL = "https://stackoverflow.com/";

    public static  void  checkSite()
    {
        try {
            URL google = new URL(siteURL);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(google.openStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { // Process each line.                
                if (inputLine.contains( wordToFind)) // System.out.println(inputLine);
                {
                    System.out.println( "Yes" );
                    return;
                }
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException me) {
            System.out.println(me);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe);
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer initalDelay = 0;
        Integer period = 10; //number of seconds to repeat

        ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                checkSite();
                // do stuff
            }
        }, initalDelay, period, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}


}
```

Comment: thank you, but how can I re-check the website every 1 minute?

Comment: I understand you

Comment: use  Integer period = 60;  this variable means the number of seconds (1 minute = 60s) between retries

Comment: may be do you know how to make an application for Windows to re-check any other words (just put word in app)?

Comment: you can create  a simple interface for it, a jframe with a textfield

Comment: Ok, for your code I receive the text: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: I changed the address only to another https://abit.itmo.ru/page/195/

Comment: it's due certification, you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908948/java-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find

Comment: It was helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/6742111/12940416