# Azure Certificate to put into truststore

Tags: java, azure, ssl, azure-active-directory, truststore

I develop a back-end application in Java. This application must be connected to Azure AD.

The application receives the id token and the access token by another front-end application.
In the back-end configuration, I try to get the public keys to verify the tokens accessing the OpenID Connect Metadata at this url : [https://login.microsoftonline.com/[TENANT-ID]/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%5BTENANT-ID%5D/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration)

To access to this url, I need to put the microsoft certificate in the Java truststore.
I retrieve the certificate from my browser and import it to the truststore.
At the starting of the application, the certificates are listed and the new one is present.
But I always have this error : `sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

I think that I import the wrong certificate in the truststore but I don't see how to resolve this.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please check if this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908948/java-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find) can help you.

Comment: Are you still facing issue here after checking the above question?