# Not able to connect the gcp services from oracle weblogic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Caused By: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem

```
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1728)

    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:304)

    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)

    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)

    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)

    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)

    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:919)

    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:916)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1369)

    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doTasks(JSSEFilterImpl.java:205)

    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:111)

    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:75)

    at weblogic.socket.JSSESocket.startHandshake(JSSESocket.java:219)

    at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:563)

    at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:534)

    at weblogic.net.http.HttpsURLConnection.connect(HttpsURLConnection.java:248)

    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:341)

    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:113)

    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)

    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012)

    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:454)

    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:164)

    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:149)

    at com.google.auth.Credentials.blockingGetToCallback(Credentials.java:103)

    at com.google.auth.Credentials$1.run(Credentials.java:92)

    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)

    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused By: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

```
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)

    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)

    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)

    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)

    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)

    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:105)

    at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(JaTrustManager.java:128)

    at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:936)

    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)

    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)

    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)

    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:919)

    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:916)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1369)

    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doTasks(JSSEFilterImpl.java:205)

    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:111)

    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:75)

    at weblogic.socket.JSSESocket.startHandshake(JSSESocket.java:219)

    at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:563)

    at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:534)

    at weblogic.net.http.HttpsURLConnection.connect(HttpsURLConnection.java:248)

    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:341)

    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:113)

    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)

    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012)

    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:454)

    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:164)

    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:149)

    at com.google.auth.Credentials.blockingGetToCallback(Credentials.java:103)

    at com.google.auth.Credentials$1.run(Credentials.java:92)

    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)

    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused By: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

```
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)

    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)

    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)

    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)

    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)

    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)

    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)

    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)

    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:105)

    at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(JaTrustManager.java:128)

    at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:936)

    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)

    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)

    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)

    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:919)

    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:916)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1369)

    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doTasks(JSSEFilterImpl.java:205)

    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:111)

    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:75)

    at weblogic.socket.JSSESocket.startHandshake(JSSESocket.java:219)

    at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:563)

    at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:534)

    at weblogic.net.http.HttpsURLConnection.connect(HttpsURLConnection.java:248)

    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:341)

    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:113)

    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)

    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012)

    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:454)

    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:164)

    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:149)

    at com.google.auth.Credentials.blockingGetToCallback(Credentials.java:103)

    at com.google.auth.Credentials$1.run(Credentials.java:92)

    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)

    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: can anyone please let me know the Answer for this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908948/java-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find)