# Log4j 2.15.0 update issue

Tags: log4j, log4j2

My application is using Log4j 2.11.1 now.  Because of the [Log4j security vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4Shell) reported a couple of days ago, I need to update Log4j to 2.15.0.  But it fails when I deploy my application on a Linux server.

Here is the error message:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ***: Could not resolve
> dependencies for project ***:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect
> dependencies at org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.15.0: Failed
> to read artifact descriptor for
> org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.15.0: Could not transfer
> artifact org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:pom:2.15.0 from/to central
> (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2):
> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]

I've added the certificate of [Maven 2](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2) to my Java keystore, but it does not work. My Java version is 1.8.181.

Answer (score 3):

I had *log4j-core* and *log4j-api* which needed to be updated. It is a similar case as you had, deployment on as a Linux server. It works for me.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.15.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.15.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I added these dependencies and updated the maven project (in the Eclipse IDE, right click on *Project* → *Go to Maven* → *Update Project*).

#### Log4j Vulnerability issue with later versions

The version Log4j 2.15.0 was released as a possible fix for this critical vulnerability, but this version was found to be still vulnerable (by [Apache Software Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Apache_Software_Foundation)).

Solution: Log4j 2.16.0 fixes this issue by removing support for message lookup patterns and disabling [JNDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface) functionality by default.

Comment: I added the above dependencies, but still my dependency tree shows below only, +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.11.2:compile

Any reason for this?

Comment: @SathishKumar- do share the exact logs of the compilation error if issue still there. part of the dependency tree doesn't give clue about it.

Comment: I have found the problem, it was from a transitive dependency coming in from one of other projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at *[Maven, Ivy, Gradle, and SBT Artifacts](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html)*.

In my case I had to switch from 1.2.x version to 2.16.0.

You can try using this dependency:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but an artifact named "log4j-1.2-api" is not found.

Answer (score 0):

As Log4j security vulnerabilities are addressed in log4j-core, please try the latest version of log4j-core using a Maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.16.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Reference - *[Maven Repository: log4j](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j)*

Regarding the exception you are facing, this may help you -
*[Java: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908948/java-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find)*

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for a *"PKIX path building failed"* error in Maven:

If you are on Windows and your IT folks have added transparent proxies that intercept [SSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) traffic, you'll want to set MAVEN_OPTS to the following:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=Windows-MY -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT
```

This will direct Maven to use the Windows trust store when vetting SSL certificates issued internally by your IT staff.

If it is a transparent proxy peeking at SSL, but you're not in Windows, you may need to add that certificate to your JVMs trusted keystore, as the JVM options I have only work on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with the following dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I replaced the above dependency with:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It works OK.