# Error while post request using spring webclient :unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: windows, maven, intellij-idea, java-11, spring-webclient

On running a code I am getting the error: `unable to find valid certification path to requested target`
I am making a simple HTTP POST call to reqres.in/api/users. What could be the reason for this?
**Code:**

```
@Test
    public void simplePostReqTest() throws URISyntaxException {
        WebClient client = WebClient.create();

        MultiValueMap<String, String> bodyValues = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

        bodyValues.add("name", "olu");
        bodyValues.add("job", "apple");

        String response = client.post()
                .uri(new URI("https://reqres.in/api/users"))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(bodyValues))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();
        System.out.println(response);
    }
```

**ERROR:**

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils (file:/C:/Users/BH21251/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.3.16/spring-core-5.3.16.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141)
    Suppressed: The stacktrace has been enhanced by Reactor, refer to additional information below: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Request to POST https://reqres.in/api/users [DefaultWebClient]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:55)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:204)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.whenError(FluxRetryWhen.java:225)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenOtherSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:274)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:415)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:251)
        at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:491)
        at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.tryEmitNext(EmitterProcessor.java:299)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManySerialized.tryEmitNext(SinkManySerialized.java:100)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalManySink.emitNext(InternalManySink.java:27)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:190)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:194)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect$ClientTransportSubscriber.onError(HttpClientConnect.java:304)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:194)
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onUncaughtException(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:201)
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnection.onUncaughtException(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:450)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.exceptionCaught(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:129)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:302)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:273)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:424)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerAdapter.java:92)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$1.fireExceptionCaught(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:145)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:143)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.exceptionCaught(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:231)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:302)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:273)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider$SslReadHandler.userEventTriggered(SslProvider.java:834)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:332)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:324)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handleUnwrapThrowable(SslHandler.java:1259)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1240)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1284)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:510)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:449)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:279)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1707)
        at com.macys.notification.enclaveapi.EncalveAPITest.simplePostReqTest(EncalveAPITest.java:75)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
        at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:312)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:478)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1081)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1068)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1015)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1548)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1394)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1235)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1284)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:510)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:449)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:279)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:276)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1335)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 37 more


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908948/java-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find)

Comment: @WoAiNii I will try the steps there. But the API call works in postman. Why do I get this error in Intellij? What could be the reason for that

Comment: Do you use the same protocol(https) with both? The error says that java can't find a valid certificate, or chain, within its cacert repository for that site, so you need to add it. For info about Postman certificate managing try to look [here](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/#managing-certificates). Check also if the ssl certificate is valid.

Comment: yes, the protocol is the same. I will check if certificates are added in postman, because I imported lot of collections and it worked directly