# SonarQube server [xxx] can not be reached

Tags: angular, sonarqube, sonarscanner

Please I have an issue with my sonarqube instance. I installed a personal sonarqube instance on our VPS under the domain name 'https://sonar.pamwork.com' and it is loading perfectly on the browser. But now I have an Angular project that I need to test with that sonarqube instance and it is not working. I configured it with sonar-scanner instance. It tells me "SonarQube server [https://sonar.pamwork.com] can not be reached. could you help me please ?

below the output of console when I use 'sonar-scanner -X':

```
> sonar-scanner -X

16:53:11.861 INFO: Scanner configuration file: C:\Users\TonkaIn-2022001\Documents\PAMWork Project\client\PAM Work Employees\node_modules\sonar-scanner\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
16:53:11.869 INFO: Project root configuration file: C:\Users\TonkaIn-2022001\Documents\PAMWork Project\client\PAM Work Employees\sonar-project.properties
16:53:11.938 INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.1.0.1141
16:53:11.939 INFO: Java 11.0.15.1 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
16:53:11.939 INFO: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
16:53:12.183 DEBUG: keyStore is : 
16:53:12.184 DEBUG: keyStore type is : pkcs12
16:53:12.185 DEBUG: keyStore provider is :
16:53:12.186 DEBUG: init keystore
16:53:12.187 DEBUG: init keymanager of type SunX509
16:53:12.877 DEBUG: Create: C:\Users\TonkaIn-2022001\.sonar\cache
16:53:12.879 INFO: User cache: C:\Users\TonkaIn-2022001\.sonar\cache
16:53:12.881 DEBUG: Create: C:\Users\TonkaIn-2022001\.sonar\cache\_tmp
16:53:12.886 DEBUG: Extract sonar-scanner-api-batch in temp...
16:53:12.903 DEBUG: Get bootstrap index...
16:53:12.903 DEBUG: Download: https://sonar.pamwork.com/batch/index
16:53:14.267 ERROR: SonarQube server [https://sonar.pamwork.com] can not be reached
16:53:14.268 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
16:53:14.269 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
16:53:14.270 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
16:53:14.271 INFO: Total time: 2.454s
16:53:14.290 INFO: Final Memory: 3M/14M
16:53:14.291 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
16:53:14.291 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarQube
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:85)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:74)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:70)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart(EmbeddedScanner.java:167)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start(EmbeddedScanner.java:113)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:73)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to get bootstrap index from server
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex(BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:42)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.getScannerEngineFiles(JarDownloader.java:58)    
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:53)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:76)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:369)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:312)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:478)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:456)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:199)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1377)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1290)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:411)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:383)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:281)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:251)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:151)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:195)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.callUrl(ServerConnection.java:113)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:98)     
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex(BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:39)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)        
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)  
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1341)
        ... 43 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)     
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
        ... 49 more
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pam-work@0.0.0 sonar: `sonar-scanner -X`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pam-work@0.0.0 sonar script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\TonkaIn-2022001\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-17T15_53_14_582Z-debug.log
```

I am launching it from my local computer and my sonar-project.properties file looks like below:

```
sonar.host.url=https://sonar.pamwork.com
sonar.login=login
sonar.password=pass
sonar.projectKey=key
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.sources=src
sonar.tests=src
sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.ts
sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=coveragecob/chrome/lcov.info
sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=reports/ut_report.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the key is:

> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12146838/1820778) your sonarqube site might be using a self-signed certificate or maybe your firewall is breaking the TLS tunnel with its own certificate and sonar does not rely on the CA used for that.

Comment: Ok @Pedro I try it and I come back to you. Thanks