# PKIX building failed:sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java

I am running an application in Eclipse locally. It tries to connect to an external URL to fetch some data. This application works fine from browser, but when I try the same from Eclipse as localhost, I get the below error:

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:456)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:323)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:271)
```

Many solutions, have mentioned to add the URL certificate from the browser using keytool. This application shows "This site does not have a certificate.". The application URL does not have a certificate.

In this case, how can I fix this issue without a certificate to install?

Regards,
R

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are running any java based application on a web server(e.g. Tomcat) with **HTTPS** enabled.

If you donot have signed any self certificate, then following link can help:
[How to configure Tomcat to support SSL or https](https://mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-support-ssl-or-https/)

Further this link has discussed the matter in detail:
[Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908948/java-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find?rq=1)