# Getting error after start react-native application

Tags: node.js, react-native, visual-studio-code, android-studio-3.0

I am new to react-native applications.
I followed reactnative original documentation to create a new application with react native CLI where OS is Windows and the device is Android. My emulator is working fine but the project is not starting.
[text](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

I installed all the prerequisites for this and was also able to create an application. But when I start my project from cmd with this command npx react-nativ run-android.
Then I get one error that I am not able to solve:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

[image: image file]

I googled this I think this error is related to Java certificate. but I don't have much knowledge there.

Answer (score 0):

this should answer it, you need to setup a certificate in order to get this working.

[Java: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19577333/10648655)

Comment: Kindly provide step-by-step tutorial for Windows please, I am new to that.