# ColdFusion 2018: I/O Exception: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: coldfusion, ssl-certificate, cfhttp, coldfusion-2018

I am facing an issue in my application when calling HTTPS services with  CFHTTP we are using below versions:

**ERROR**
I/O Exception: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

**Server Product ColdFusion**

Version 2018,0,19,330149

Edition Enterprise

Operating System UNIX

**JAVA**

java version “11.0.17” 2022-10-18 LTS

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.17+10-LTS-269)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.17+10-LTS-269, mixed mode

**TOMCAT SERVER**

Please let me know if any details required.

Thanks!

Comment: *unable to find valid certification path to requested target* You didn't tell us what that target is

Comment: Where are you using the certificate? Share the code and configuration?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908948/java-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find)

Comment: My Application is build on ColdFusion app server

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what types of services you are calling, it can be difficult to diagnose the problem. However, I will try.

The error message tells me that Java is having trouble with finding a certification path.  This tells us that the certification path is not in the Java key store.

My first guess would be that you are calling a self-hosted service that is using an internal certificate authority signed cert, or possibly a self-signed cert. Or possibly a cert from some obscure certificate authority that does not have a CA entry in the Java key store.

For any of the above issues, the answer is to load the cert of the CA or of the self-signed certificate into the Java key store. Note: this will require a restart of the ColdFusion server.

First, you need to obtain the needed certificates. Since I don't know what services you are calling, I cannot tell you where to get those.

Then you need to location your Java key store (cacerts) that ColdFusion uses. If you are using the built-in Java, you should find it in /jre/lib/security.

Finally, you need to load the cert into the key store, which you can do with the following command.

At a command prompt or terminal window navigate to the JRE /bin folder and run

```
keytool -importcert -keystore lib/security/cacerts - alias GiveTheCertAnAliasName -file path/to/the/cert/file
```

As I mentioned above, you will need to restart ColdFusion before the new cert can be used in your calls.