I am able to run app on IOS simulator but not in android emulator due to unable to find valid certification path to requested target
I am having this issue when trying to run android emulator in flutter.
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)

I suspect that the server's SSL certificate is not trusted by the Java runtime environment.
I tried to import the certificate into the Java Truststore using keytool but still having the error.

keytool -import -alias example.com -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -file server-cert.pe

Please help advise. I just started to learn about certificate and not sure if this is the root cause.
flutter doctor
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.6, on macOS 14.7 23H124 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.4)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.92.2)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] Network resources

$JAVA_HOME
/Users/X/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-19.0.2/Contents/Home

gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.11.1-all.zip

Debug Console
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
3
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(Unknown Source)
2
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(Unknown Source)
2
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)


Please check this answer. : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51243676/4373661
