# Unable to import certificate in keytool

Tags: android, authentication, keytool

I am using following command to import the certificate in KeyStore:

```
"%JAVA_HOME%"\bin\keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -alias c:\cacert-Service -file c:\e-Service.cer -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%"\jre\lib\security\cacerts
```

it asked for a password, and show the following result on CMD:

```
 Certificate was added to keystore
 keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6
 .0_20\jre\lib\security\cacerts (Access is denied)
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321211/java-keytool-error-after-importing-certificate-keytool-error-java-io-filenot?rq=1

Comment: This could happen if you are not running the command prompt in administrator mode. If you are using windows7, you can go to run, type cmd and hit Ctrl+Shift+enter. This will open the command prompt in administrator mode. If not, you can also go to start -> all programs -> accessories -> right click command prompt and say run as administrator.

Comment: so can put it as answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could happen if you are not running the command prompt in administrator mode. If you are using windows7, you can go to run, type cmd and hit Ctrl+Shift+enter. This will open the command prompt in administrator mode. If not, you can also go to start -> all programs -> accessories -> right click command prompt and say run as administrator.

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321211/java-keytool-error-after-importing-certificate-keytool-error-java-io-filenot?rq=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I am able to import certificate in Keytool by opening command pompt in administrator mode by using `start -> all programs -> accessories -> right click command prompt and say run as administrator`