# java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Operation not permitted) error with ./keytool -import on mac osx (el capitan) - Java 6

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

Trying to import a CA Cert to my Java 6 truststore and am running into this error:

```
./keytool -v -import -trustcacerts -alias Rapidssl -file /Users/spurr/Desktop/rapidssl.cer -keystore /System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts
Enter keystore password:
Certificate was added to keystore
[Storing /System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts]
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts (Operation not permitted)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts (Operation not permitted)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:84)
at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(KeyTool.java:902)
at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:172)
at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:166)
```

I'm running that command as root as well so I'd think I have access to that cacerts keystore location.  Using Java 6.

Comment: are you in your home dir? I would update the JVM

Comment: this is what my $JAVA_HOME shows `$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: I meant form where you are issuing the command

Comment: further more - the `lib/security/cacerts` file is a symlink to a different `cacerts` file on my system - `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security $ ls -al | grep cacerts
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel     81 Jan  5 11:13 cacerts -> /System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts`

Comment: i'm issuing the command from `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin`

Comment: I think you should try this in your home dir for many reasons

Comment: I just tried to in my home directory without any success `~ $ sudo /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias Rapidssl -file /Users/spurr/Desktop/rapidssl.cer -keystore /System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts` and got the same result as before
`Enter keystore password:
Certificate was added to keystore
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts (Operation not permitted)`

Comment: as joeDoe user? Who is the actual user of the certs?

Comment: do man key tool. Keystores are created in the home directory of the user issuing the command.

Comment: the user that I login with - I'm running an application called "youtrack workflow editor" that uses java 6

Comment: sudo is superuser do. Remove the sudo and try it from your home dir. It works for me.

Comment: i've run the same command without `sudo` and got the same result.  I'm also using the embedded `keytool` from within java - not from a local binary.

Comment: I am out of ideas. Sudo will create the keystore in the root home dir. Probably something you don't want. My keytool points to /usr/bin/keytool which is a link to /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/keytool

Comment: I don't want to "create" a keystore - I want to import a cacert into an existing cacerts keystore.

Comment: The keystore is created when you import by default. So if the tool is pointing to a dir that has restrictions you would probably get the exception

Comment: what do you mean the keystore is "created"?  I'm trying to import to an existing keystore using `-keystore /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/lib/security/cacerts` - what is there to create in this case?  it already exists.

Comment: this stackoverflow suggests it's an administrator level (sudo for mac) issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321211/java-keytool-error-after-importing-certificate-keytool-error-java-io-filenot?rq=1 although i'm still running into the issue

Comment: The file not found exception is stating that you are not hitting the right keystore.

Comment: I just got it to work - it looks like it's a mac osx specific issue - you have to disable `csrutil` first during a reboot and then it will allow you to important certs to that keystore.  Here's how it looks now - `sudo keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias rapidssl -file ~/Desktop/rapidssl.cer -keystore /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/lib/security/cacerts` and the result is
`Password:
Enter keystore password:
Certificate was added to keystore`

Comment: can you do it now as joseDoe?

Comment: no, now I get a (permission denied) error when not using `sudo` - `keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/lib/security/cacerts (Permission denied)` - but that makes sense to me because the cacerts keystore I'm trying to import into is owned by `root`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was hit by similar issue on MacOS Big Sur while starting an jnlp file:

```
CouldNotLoadArgumentException[ Could not load file/URL specified: /Users/jhartman/Documents/Favorities/NCC/NCC 123.jnlp]
....
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/jhartman/Documents/Favorities/NCC/NCC 123.jnlp (Operation not permitted)
```

Solution for this was:

- Give Java (`/usr/bin/java`) *Full Disk* access
- Give Java (`/usr/bin/java`) *Files and Folders* access to Downloads, Documents and Folders

**Steps**

1. Open `/usr/bin` in Finder, e.g. by invoking from Terminal:

```
jhartman@MBP ~ % open /usr/bin
```

2. Localise `java` (and `keytool`)
3. Open *System Preferences* and *Security & Privacy*. Open *Full Disk Access* tab and authorise
4. Drag `java` and `keytool` from Finder window opened in step 1 and drop onto the App list in *Full Disk Access*

[image]

5. Go to *Security & Privacy* -> *Files and Folders*, tick Downloads Folder and Document Folder for `java` and `keytool`

[image]

It was solution for my problem but I hope it should also sort out `keytool` issue.

Comment: If even after providing required permissions and restart the issue persists, move the required files in src/main/resources folder.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a mac specific issue when the exception states `(Operation not permitted)` -

For anyone else having this problem you need to reboot your mac and press ⌘+R when booting up. Then go into Utilities > Terminal and type the following commands:

```
csrutil disable
reboot
```

You should be able to import cacerts to your Java keystore following that.  Don't forget to reenable `csrutil` after you've imported that cacert.  Reboot, press ⌘+R when booting up, Utilities > Terminal, enter:

```
csrutil enable
reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this for files under my .metadata directory because I put my Eclipse workspace under Documents. Get around this by going into System Preferences->Privacy and adding access to particular Files and Folder for Eclipse or giving Eclipse Full Disk Access.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy the file and rename it to cacerts_backup
2. Copy the cacerts to your user/downloads (or whatever you want) directory
3. Modify the cacerts file
4. Copy it back and replace the original file