# Not able to access jarfile on desktop in Macos 11

Tags: java, jenkins, jar, executable-jar, macos-big-sur

I want to connect mac machine to jenkins as a node. For that I'm using agent.jar file. While running

```
java -jar agent.jar
```

I'm getting following error -

```
Error : Unable to access jarfile agent.jar
```

If I move this jarfile to another directory like home directory it works but not on desktop. Permission is not the problem here as I have provided executable permission to this file. It doesn't work in sudo too on desktop folder.

What could be the issue?

Comment: MacOS has a security measurement active that disallows programs access to certain user folders. You have to grant `/usr/bin/java` full disc access in security settings. Also make sure to run the command in a UI terminal because sometimes a popup windows asks if you want to grant access.

Comment: Did provide full disk access to /usr/bin/java still facing same issue and don't know what is UI terminal :(

Comment: UI terminal is the regular terminal program you start. I mentioned that just in case you are working via SSH on the MacOS system (SSH console = non-UI access).

Comment: Got it. I have full access to Mac System so that should not be a problem. It didn't ask for any permission or anything while trying to run that command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve this after dragging /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java to Full disk access under Security and privacy.

Comment: You mean provide Terminal with Full Disk access