# keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: cacerts (Access is denied)

Tags: java-8, windows-10, keytool

This question has been asked several times but none of the solutions work for me.  I running the DOS command window as Administrator, but when running the keytool command to install a certificate I get the error above:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\security>keytool -import -file xxx.yyy.zzz.crt -alias xxxx.yyy.zzz.com -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt
Certificate was added to keystore
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: cacerts (Access is denied)
```

I'm on Windows 10 with JDK 1.8.0_191.  Why would access be denied to the Administator?

Comment: Seems to be the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321211/java-keytool-error-after-importing-certificate-keytool-error-java-io-filenot). Please have a look.

Answer (score 5):

"Run as administrator Command prompt" has fixed this issue at Windows.

Answer (score 4):

I have faced the same issue.

Here is the solution what I found:

1. Copy the cacert file other than Java folder [May be D drive or desktop].
2. Update the path of cacert file path in your command [Sated in question].
3. Run your query. [You wont get the io exception].
4. Then replace the new cacert file in the original location.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I did not have true admin rights to my Windows 10 laptop.  I had enough permissions to install the JDK to the default location (which requires admin rights), but not enough rights to use keytool.

I uninstalled the JDK from the default location  and reinstalled it in a directory that was not restricted to admin users.  Then keytool worked properly.