# Cannot make basic http authentication work in Jersey

Tags: java, rest, ssl, jersey, jersey-client

I am trying to connect to a secure external rest service using Jersey 1.X version.

I used the following code

```
public class MyRestClient
{
  private static final String API_USER_NAME = "some value";
  private static final String API_PASSWORD = "some value";
  private static final String REST_URL = "https://<somevalue>";

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);
    client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(API_USER_NAME, API_PASSWORD));
    WebResource webResource =
      client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri(REST_URL).build());

    ClientResponse response = webResource.post(ClientResponse.class);
    System.out.println(response);
  }
}
```

But I keep hitting this exception..

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching 'somevalue' found
```

I checked out the API of this external rest service and it says it support  Basic HTTP authentication but I dont know why I keep hitting this error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: That's not a problem of authentication but of validating SSL certificates. How is the certificated used by the server signed? Is the CA known to Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTPS using Jersey Client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145431/https-using-jersey-client)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the lack of security in Basic Auth by itself, it's usually done over SSL, as you can see in the `https` schema in the URL. With SSL, there are [certificates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) used. The SSL handshake consists of the server sending its certificate and the client checking its truststore to see if the certificate is trusted. The platform should have a list of Certificate authorities that it trusts. For instance if we try and access

```
WebTarget target = client.target("https://wikipedia.org");
```

this will work as the cert sent by wikipedia is signed by a trusted authority in the system. On the other hand, if the certificate from the server is not signed by one of those trused authorities, then the SSL handshake will fail.

If this is the case, then `Client` needs to be configured to handle the SSL handshake, that's why you are getting the exception. You can see some good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2145431/2587435) on how to configure the `Client` for working with `https`

---

### UPDATE

> The link you have provided is dead so I dont know what 'myTrustManager' and 'hostnameVerifier' is...can you share some info on how can I supply that?

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.HTTPSProperties;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import org.junit.Test;

public class JUnitTest {

    private static final String TRUSTSTORE_FILE = "<location-of-truststore";
    private static final String TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD = "trustStorePassword";

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        truststore.load(new FileInputStream(TRUSTSTORE_FILE), 
                                            TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        tmf.init(truststore);
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        config.getProperties().put(HTTPSProperties.PROPERTY_HTTPS_PROPERTIES, 
                new HTTPSProperties(null, sslContext));
        Client client = Client.create(config);

        final String httpsUrl = "https://...";
        ClientResponse response = client.resource(httpsUrl).get(ClientResponse.class);
        System.out.println(response.getStatus());
        System.out.println(response.getEntity(String.class));
    } 
}
```

Basically you need to get the [X.509 Certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) from the people who own the API (see link below for programmatic way). Then you import it into your trust store. This is how your client knows to trust the connection. If you trust that the server is who they say they are, then the connection can be encrypted.

Once you have the cert you can import it with the [Java keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/820-3748/gghyy/index.html). By doing this

> `keytool -import -alias serverCert -file <cert.file> -keystore <client_trust_file>`

You will be asked for a password. Then asked if you trust the cert. Type 'yes', then you're done. This is the file (`client_trust_file`) and password you typed, should be used in the above code.

- [**Programmaticly add a remote certificate to your truststore**](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-do-i-programatically-extract-a-certificate-from-a-site-and-add-it-to-my-keystore)
- See more about [Java Secure Socket Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html)

---

## Update 2

Instructions on creating a simple app that is over a secured SSL connection with Tomcat. The use the client code above to access it. I am going to be using Netbeans 8, but will try to include instructions for doing this in a general way also. I will also be using Tomcat 8 (the configuration may be a bit different fro Tomcat 7. You should consult the documentation for any differences). I will be using Maven, so hopefully you are comfortable using it.

#### Step 1:

Crate a new app. I will create a simple Jersey app from a Maven archetype. In Netbeans

> File → New Project → Maven → Project from Archetype → Search "jersey-quickstart-webapp"; choose the one with groupId "org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes" → Next → Name the project "secured-rest-app" → Hopefully you can complete the rest. You should end up with a Maven app.

In any other IDE that supports Maven, just look for an archetype with the coordinates:

- groupId: org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes
- artifactId: jersey-quickstart-webapp
- version: 2.13

From command line: do

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-grizzly2 \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false \
    -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=secured-rest-app -Dpackage=secured.rest.app \
    -DarchetypeVersion=2.13
```

#### Step 2:

We need to set up Basic Authentication in the app. This can be done in the web.xm l. Open up the web.xml of the project and add this below the `</servlet-mapping>`

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Secured Rest App</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>secured-rest-app.com</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

#### Step 3:

Now we just need to set up the realm in Tomcat. By default Tomcat use a realm names `UserDatabaseRealm`. It basically just reads from an xml file. This is probably not the most desired way in production, but this is the easiest to work with for an example. For more information on realms, see [Realm Configuration HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html). For this particular realm, the file is already set up. We just need to add our user. Open the `<tomcat-home>/conf/tomcat-users.xml` and enter the following user inside `<tomcat-users>`

```
<user password="secret" roles="user" username="peeskillet"/>
```

#### Step 4:

Now we can test it. If you already have Tomcat setup on Netbeans, all we need to do is `Run` and select the server. This should automatically open up the browser to our `index.jsp`. The file is not secured, as it doesn't fit within the `<url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>` of out security constraint. Click the Jersey Resource link and you will see the Basic Auth login. Type in `peeskillet` and `secret` for the username and password, respectively. Now you can access the resource.

#### Step 5:

All of the above just set us up for Basic Authentication, but because all Basic Auth is, is just base64 encoding our username and password, it can be easily decoded, so we need to authenticate over a secure connection.

First thing we need to do is create a keystore for our server. What we will be going here is creating a self signed certificate, which should only be done in development. In production, you will want to get a cert from a trusted CA authority

`cd` to `<tomcat-home>/conf` and type the following (all on one line)

```
keytool -genkey -alias localhost -keyalg RSA -keysize 1024
        -dname "CN=localhost"
        -keypass supersecret
        -keystore tomcat-keystore.jks
        -storepass supersecret
```

You should now see a file `tomcat-keystore.jks` in the `conf` dir. Now we can export the certificate.

```
keytool -export -alias localhost -rfc -keystore ./tomcat-keystore.jks > ./tomcat.cert
```

You will be prompted for the password, type `supersecret`. You should now see a `tomcat.cert` file created in the `conf` dir. Copy that file into the project root of your application you created above.

From the command line `cd` to the project root, the location of the `tomcat.cert` and type the following

```
keytool -import -alias tomcatCert -file ./tomcat.cert -keystore ./client-truststore.jks
```

You will be prompted for a password for the truststore. Use `trustpass`. You will need to enter it twice. When done, it will prompt to trust the certificate, type `yes` and enter. You should now see a `client-truststore.jks` file in the project root. This is what we will use for our client app.

Now we just need to configure Tomcat to use our keystore for the connection. In the `<tomcat-home>/conf/server.xml`, inside the the `<Service>` element
. (Note Tomcat 7 may be a little different)

```
<Connector port="8443" 
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    maxThreads="150" 
    SSLEnabled="true" 
    scheme="https" 
    secure="true"
    keystoreFile="absolute/path/to/tomcat-keystore.jks"
    keystorePass="supersecret"
    clientAuth="false" 
    sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

And finally, in our webapp, we should add the secure connection support by altering the `<security-constraint>`

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Secured Rest App</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Now we are set to use our client code.

#### Step 6:

The code above, uses Jersey 1 client. We are using Jersey 2, so the code will be slightly different. Anywhere in the app, just create a class with a `main` method to run our client. Here's what I use:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.authentication.HttpAuthenticationFeature;

public class SimpleClientApp {

    private static final String TRUSTSTORE_FILE = "client-truststore.jks";
    private static final String TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD = "trustpass";
    private static final String APP_URL 
            = "https://localhost:8443/secured-rest-app/webapi/myresource";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        truststore.load(new FileInputStream(TRUSTSTORE_FILE), 
                                            TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        tmf.init(truststore);
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
                .sslContext(sslContext).build();
        client.register(HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic("peeskillet", "secret"));

        Response response = client.target(APP_URL).request().get();
        System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));

    }
}
```

You should be able to run this and it should print out `Got it!`. We're done!

Since this particular question was about Jersey 1, I'll just mention that you can easily create a Jersey 1 app. From the first step, just use the coordinates for the Maven archetype

- groupId: com.sun.jersey.archetypes
- artifactId: jersey-quickstart-webapp
- version: 1.18.1

In Netbeans, just follow the steps above, but select the `com.sun.jersey.archetypes` version of the `jersey-quickstart-webapp`.

With Jersey 1, you can use the code in the original answer, just add the Basic Auth filter, as the OP has done in the original post, setting the username and password and changing the url of course.

**Please let me know if there are any mistakes in the post. I haven't gotten a chance to proof-read this yet :-)**

Some Resource

- [Tomcat 8 SSL/TLS Configuration HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html)
- [Tomcat 8 Realm Configuration HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/realm-howto.html)
- [Tomcat 7 Realm Configuration HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html)
- [Tomcat 7 SSL/TLS Configuration HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html)

Comment: The link you have provided is dead so I dont know what 'myTrustManager' and 'hostnameVerifier' is...can you share some info on how can I supply that?

Comment: Thank you @peeskillet.  I have no experience in security specially certificate but I just would like to ask you more please if you may allow.

Comment: Thank you @peeskillet.  I have no experience in security specially certificate but I just would like to ask you more please if you may allow. Currently I run my application in stand alone mode (main method), if I run my code in a web application then there is no need for me to do any more certificate importing right since I have done it already?  Assumming I transfer to a new development environment with a different jdk, then I need to do the certificate importing again correct?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use the same client code in a webapp? If so, yes you should be fine. You can use the same truststore. As long as the certificate doesn't change, you can keep using it. During the SSL handshake, the server sends the same certficate. The SSL engine verifies the certficate with the one that you have inported. If all is good, then a secured connection can be established.

Comment: You can practice for now, just to see how it works. Look into the documentation of your server/container, and look for how to set up SSL. One of the tasks should be creating a keystore for the server. From the you can export the certificate from that keystore. Then use the command above to import that certificate into your client truststore. Create simple webapp on your server, that is secure with SSL (should be configured in your web.xml), then use the client code above to try and communicate with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70826/discussion-between-mark-estrada-and-peeskillet).

Comment: Late update, but I found a way to programmatically obtain the certificate and add it to your truststore, [here](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-do-i-programatically-extract-a-certificate-from-a-site-and-add-it-to-my-keystore)