# How do I enforce my RESTEasy HTTP client to use TLSv1.2?

Tags: ssl, intellij-idea, resteasy, apache-httpclient-4.x

I tried setting the environment variable in my Intellij Idea under run/debug configurations like: -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2, as well as setting it programmatically like:

`System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");`

I also tried setting this property to my RESTEasy client directly like:

```
javax.ws.rs.client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
client.property("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
```

but with no success. What else can I do to enforce my client to use TLSv1.2?

Comment: Try and set the [`SSLContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html#getInstance%28java.lang.String%29), as seen in [step 6 of this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28472044/2587435)

Answer (score 0):

You could get the SSLContext instance and pass it to the builder as follows (exception handling omitted):

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
// The SSL context must be explicitly initialized
sslContext.init(null, null, null);
ResteasyClient restClient = new ResteasyClientBuilder().sslContext(instance).build();
```