# Grizzly Server with CLIENT_CERT Authentication

Tags: java, rest, ssl, jersey, grizzly

I am using Grizzly in order to startup a server and deploy an application which needs client certificates in order to work.

When i am starting up the Grizzly Server, i create two network listeners. A plain one which listens to **HTTP** and a secure one which is supposed to handle **HTTPS** requests. While the plain network listener behaves as expected (serves the requests without any security), the HTTPS one is not. The problem is that while i hit the HTTPS endpoint, it prompts me for my client certificate but then nothing happens and the request times out.

I have set ***"-Djava.net.debug=all"*** and i can see that the SSL handshake is happening, thus i suspect i am missing something while i set up the Grizzly server. Maybe an authenticator?

The code i use to start up the server is the below:

```
public void startServer() {
        final String contextPath = "/";
        final WebappContext webappContext = new WebappContext( "Test", contextPath );
        final Map< String, String > contextInitParams = Collections.singletonMap(
                "jersey.config.server.provider.packages", "com.mywebapp" );
        for ( Map.Entry< String, String > entry : contextInitParams.entrySet() )
        {
            webappContext.addContextInitParameter( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
            webappContext.setInitParameter( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
        }
        ServletRegistration servletRegistration = webappContext.addServlet( ServletContainer.class.getName(),
                ServletContainer.class );
        servletRegistration.addMapping( new String[] { "/*" } );
        servletRegistration.setInitParameters( contextInitParams );

        SSLContextConfigurator ssl = new SSLContextConfigurator();
        ssl.setKeyStoreFile( KEY_STORE_FILE_PATH );
        ssl.setKeyStorePass( KEY_STORE_PASSWORD );
        ssl.setTrustStoreFile( TRUSTSTORE_FILE_PATH );
        ssl.setTrustStorePass( TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD );
        ssl.setSecurityProtocol( "TLSv1.2" );

        SSLEngineConfigurator sslEngineConfigurator = new SSLEngineConfigurator( ssl, false, true, true );
        sslEngineConfigurator.setEnabledCipherSuites( new String[] { "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
                "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256", "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
                "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA", "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA" } );

        // HTTP listener
        HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer( new URI( "http://localhost:8080" ) );
        // HTTPS listener
        NetworkListener lis = new NetworkListener( "HTTPS", "localhost", 8443 );
        lis.setSecure( true );
        lis.setTraceEnabled( true );
        lis.setSSLEngineConfig( sslEngineConfigurator );
        httpServer.addListener( lis );

        httpServer.start();
        webappContext.deploy( httpServer );
        Thread.currentThread().join();
        }
```

Can anyone spot what is wrong in the above code? Maybe i am missing a handler?

Any help much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: What client are you using? I don't have time to test right now, but try it with the client api, configured as seen at the bottom of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28472044/2587435)

Comment: @peeskillet thanks for the comment. I am testing it using a Chrome browser. I can also test it programmatically using a REST client, which will carry the appropriate certificate. The initial SSL handshake seems to be happening but after that the request is timing out

Comment: Can you pls. share the testcase on github, so it'll be easier to reproduce?