# Jersey Client timeout when trying to connect to HTTPS. Cert is imported

Tags: java, ssl, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

The application is using SpringBoot and Jersey 2.0.
I'm trying to send a post request to https://wwwcie.ups.com/rest/Track. I've brought in the certificate and imported it successfully to the jvm being used by Spring. 
This application is successfully reaching other https endpoints, but for some reason there is a timeout with UPS. I can reach UPS with Postman and SoapUI just fine.

I've tried to manually create the SSLContext for this client, trusting everything... same result.

Here is my client code, the same that works elsewhere:

```
javax.ws.rs.core.Response response = ClientBuilder.newClient()
            .target(ServiceUrlUtil.getProp("ups.tracking.url"))// https://wwwcie.ups.com
            .path(ServiceUrlUtil.getProp("ups.tracking.path"))// /rest/Track
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .post(Entity.entity(upsRequest, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

Logs:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1316)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1291)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector$4.getOutputStream(HttpUrlConnector.java:385)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:200)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:194)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:228)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableOutputStream.write(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:299)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:2003)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.flush(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1019)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:891)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.writeTo(ProviderBase.java:635)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.doWriteEntity(ClientRequest.java:517)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:499)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:388)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
... 82 more


2017-04-03 15:26:29 DEBUG IdleTimeout:151 - SelectChannelEndPoint@c459f9c{/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:55786<->8080,Open,in,out,-,-,30003/30000,HttpConnection}{io=0,kio=0,kro=1} idle timeout check, elapsed: 30003 ms, remaining: -3 ms
2017-04-03 15:26:29 DEBUG IdleTimeout:158 - SelectChannelEndPoint@c459f9c{/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:55786<->8080,Open,in,out,-,-,30003/30000,HttpConnection}{io=0,kio=0,kro=1} idle timeout expired
2017-04-03 15:26:29 DEBUG WriteFlusher:455 - ignored: WriteFlusher@5b2f8631{IDLE} {}
2017-04-03 15:26:29 DEBUG AbstractEndPoint:164 - Ignored idle endpoint SelectChannelEndPoint@c459f9c{/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:55786<->8080,Open,in,out,-,-,30004/30000,HttpConnection}{io=0,kio=0,kro=1}
```

Below see SSL logs, see the UPS portion below:

```
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=wwwcie.ups.com, OU=UPS-J2EE, O=United Parcel Service, L=Mahwah, ST=New Jersey, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x704087b50cd6823c2f560f9e746528fd
  Valid from Thu Mar 05 19:00:00 EST 2015 until Tue Mar 06 18:59:59 EST 2018
```

And the full log... 
    trustStore is:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Equifax Secure Global eBusiness CA-1, O=Equifax Secure Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=Equifax Secure Global eBusiness CA-1, O=Equifax Secure Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xc3517
  Valid from Mon Jun 21 00:00:00 EDT 1999 until Mon Jun 22 00:00:00 EDT 2020

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - EC1, OU="(c) 2012 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - EC1, OU="(c) 2012 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: EC; Serial number: 0xa68b79290000000050d091f9
  Valid from Tue Dec 18 10:25:36 EST 2012 until Fri Dec 18 10:55:36 EST 2037

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=SecureTrust CA, O=SecureTrust Corporation, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=SecureTrust CA, O=SecureTrust Corporation, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xcf08e5c0816a5ad427ff0eb271859d0
  Valid from Tue Nov 07 14:31:18 EST 2006 until Mon Dec 31 14:40:55 EST 2029

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: OU=Security Communication RootCA1, O=SECOM Trust.net, C=JP
  Issuer:  OU=Security Communication RootCA1, O=SECOM Trust.net, C=JP
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x0
  Valid from Tue Sep 30 00:20:49 EDT 2003 until Sat Sep 30 00:20:49 EDT 2023

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert Global Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Global Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x83be056904246b1a1756ac95991c74a
  Valid from Thu Nov 09 19:00:00 EST 2006 until Sun Nov 09 19:00:00 EST 2031

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=QuoVadis Root CA 2 G3, O=QuoVadis Limited, C=BM
  Issuer:  CN=QuoVadis Root CA 2 G3, O=QuoVadis Limited, C=BM
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x445734245b81899b35f2ceb82b3b5ba726f07528
  Valid from Thu Jan 12 13:59:32 EST 2012 until Sun Jan 12 13:59:32 EST 2042

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert Trusted Root G4, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Trusted Root G4, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x59b1b579e8e2132e23907bda777755c
  Valid from Thu Aug 01 08:00:00 EDT 2013 until Fri Jan 15 07:00:00 EST 2038

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x18acb56afd69b6153a636cafdafac4a1
  Valid from Sun Nov 26 19:00:00 EST 2006 until Wed Jul 16 19:59:59 EDT 2036

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: OU=Security Communication RootCA2, O="SECOM Trust Systems CO.,LTD.", C=JP
  Issuer:  OU=Security Communication RootCA2, O="SECOM Trust Systems CO.,LTD.", C=JP
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x0
  Valid from Fri May 29 01:00:39 EDT 2009 until Tue May 29 01:00:39 EDT 2029

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU="(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU="(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x7dd9fe07cfa81eb7107967fba78934c6
  Valid from Sun May 17 20:00:00 EDT 1998 until Tue Aug 01 19:59:59 EDT 2028

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: OU=ePKI Root Certification Authority, O="Chunghwa Telecom Co., Ltd.", C=TW
  Issuer:  OU=ePKI Root Certification Authority, O="Chunghwa Telecom Co., Ltd.", C=TW
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x15c8bd65475cafb897005ee406d2bc9d
  Valid from Sun Dec 19 21:31:27 EST 2004 until Tue Dec 19 21:31:27 EST 2034

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=AffirmTrust Commercial, O=AffirmTrust, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=AffirmTrust Commercial, O=AffirmTrust, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x7777062726a9b17c
  Valid from Fri Jan 29 09:06:06 EST 2010 until Tue Dec 31 09:06:06 EST 2030

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Certum Trusted Network CA, OU=Certum Certification Authority, O=Unizeto Technologies S.A., C=PL
  Issuer:  CN=Certum Trusted Network CA, OU=Certum Certification Authority, O=Unizeto Technologies S.A., C=PL
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x444c0
  Valid from Wed Oct 22 08:07:37 EDT 2008 until Mon Dec 31 07:07:37 EST 2029

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=XRamp Global Certification Authority, O=XRamp Security Services Inc, OU=www.xrampsecurity.com, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=XRamp Global Certification Authority, O=XRamp Security Services Inc, OU=www.xrampsecurity.com, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x50946cec18ead59c4dd597ef758fa0ad
  Valid from Mon Nov 01 12:14:04 EST 2004 until Mon Jan 01 00:37:19 EST 2035

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Sonera Class2 CA, O=Sonera, C=FI
  Issuer:  CN=Sonera Class2 CA, O=Sonera, C=FI
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1d
  Valid from Fri Apr 06 03:29:40 EDT 2001 until Tue Apr 06 03:29:40 EDT 2021

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=America Online Root Certification Authority 1, O=America Online Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=America Online Root Certification Authority 1, O=America Online Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1
  Valid from Tue May 28 02:00:00 EDT 2002 until Thu Nov 19 15:43:00 EST 2037

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority - G2, OU=(c) 2007 GeoTrust Inc. - For authorized use only, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority - G2, OU=(c) 2007 GeoTrust Inc. - For authorized use only, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: EC; Serial number: 0x3cb2f4480a00e2feeb243b5e603ec36b
  Valid from Sun Nov 04 19:00:00 EST 2007 until Mon Jan 18 18:59:59 EST 2038

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority, O=Equifax, C=US
  Issuer:  OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority, O=Equifax, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x35def4cf
  Valid from Sat Aug 22 12:41:51 EDT 1998 until Wed Aug 22 12:41:51 EDT 2018

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=COMODO ECC Certification Authority, O=COMODO CA Limited, L=Salford, ST=Greater Manchester, C=GB
  Issuer:  CN=COMODO ECC Certification Authority, O=COMODO CA Limited, L=Salford, ST=Greater Manchester, C=GB
  Algorithm: EC; Serial number: 0x1f47afaa62007050544c019e9b63992a
  Valid from Wed Mar 05 19:00:00 EST 2008 until Mon Jan 18 18:59:59 EST 2038

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x2ac5c266a0b409b8f0b79f2ae462577
  Valid from Thu Nov 09 19:00:00 EST 2006 until Sun Nov 09 19:00:00 EST 2031

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GeoTrust Universal CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=GeoTrust Universal CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1
  Valid from Thu Mar 04 00:00:00 EST 2004 until Sun Mar 04 00:00:00 EST 2029

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3
  Issuer:  CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x4000000000121585308a2
  Valid from Wed Mar 18 06:00:00 EDT 2009 until Sun Mar 18 06:00:00 EDT 2029

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root, OU=CyberTrust, O=Baltimore, C=IE
  Issuer:  CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root, OU=CyberTrust, O=Baltimore, C=IE
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x20000b9
  Valid from Fri May 12 14:46:00 EDT 2000 until Mon May 12 19:59:00 EDT 2025

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Thawte Timestamping CA, OU=Thawte Certification, O=Thawte, L=Durbanville, ST=Western Cape, C=ZA
  Issuer:  CN=Thawte Timestamping CA, OU=Thawte Certification, O=Thawte, L=Durbanville, ST=Western Cape, C=ZA
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x67c8e1e8e3be1cbdfc913b8ea6238749
  Valid from Tue Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1996 until Fri Jan 01 18:59:59 EST 2021

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=AAA Certificate Services, O=Comodo CA Limited, L=Salford, ST=Greater Manchester, C=GB
  Issuer:  CN=AAA Certificate Services, O=Comodo CA Limited, L=Salford, ST=Greater Manchester, C=GB
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1
  Valid from Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 2003 until Sun Dec 31 18:59:59 EST 2028

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: OU=Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority, O="Starfield Technologies, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  OU=Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority, O="Starfield Technologies, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x0
  Valid from Tue Jun 29 13:39:16 EDT 2004 until Thu Jun 29 13:39:16 EDT 2034

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Chambers of Commerce Root, OU=http://www.chambersign.org, O=AC Camerfirma SA CIF A82743287, C=EU
  Issuer:  CN=Chambers of Commerce Root, OU=http://www.chambersign.org, O=AC Camerfirma SA CIF A82743287, C=EU
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x0
  Valid from Tue Sep 30 12:13:43 EDT 2003 until Wed Sep 30 12:13:44 EDT 2037

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=UTN-USERFirst-Hardware, OU=http://www.usertrust.com, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Salt Lake City, ST=UT, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=UTN-USERFirst-Hardware, OU=http://www.usertrust.com, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Salt Lake City, ST=UT, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x44be0c8b500024b411d3362afe650afd
  Valid from Fri Jul 09 14:10:42 EDT 1999 until Tue Jul 09 14:19:22 EDT 2019

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3, OU="(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3, OU="(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x9b7e0649a33e62b9d5ee90487129ef57
  Valid from Thu Sep 30 20:00:00 EDT 1999 until Wed Jul 16 19:59:59 EDT 2036

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GlobalSign Root CA, OU=Root CA, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
  Issuer:  CN=GlobalSign Root CA, OU=Root CA, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x40000000001154b5ac394
  Valid from Tue Sep 01 08:00:00 EDT 1998 until Fri Jan 28 07:00:00 EST 2028

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=UTN-USERFirst-Object, OU=http://www.usertrust.com, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Salt Lake City, ST=UT, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=UTN-USERFirst-Object, OU=http://www.usertrust.com, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Salt Lake City, ST=UT, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x44be0c8b500024b411d3362de0b35f1b
  Valid from Fri Jul 09 14:31:20 EDT 1999 until Tue Jul 09 14:40:36 EDT 2019

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=AffirmTrust Networking, O=AffirmTrust, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=AffirmTrust Networking, O=AffirmTrust, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x7c4f04391cd4992d
  Valid from Fri Jan 29 09:08:24 EST 2010 until Tue Dec 31 09:08:24 EST 2030

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=AffirmTrust Premium, O=AffirmTrust, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=AffirmTrust Premium, O=AffirmTrust, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x6d8c1446b1a60aee
  Valid from Fri Jan 29 09:10:36 EST 2010 until Mon Dec 31 09:10:36 EST 2040

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Code Signing Root, OU=CyberTrust, O=Baltimore, C=IE
  Issuer:  CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Code Signing Root, OU=CyberTrust, O=Baltimore, C=IE
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x20000bf
  Valid from Wed May 17 10:01:00 EDT 2000 until Sat May 17 19:59:00 EDT 2025

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=America Online Root Certification Authority 2, O=America Online Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=America Online Root Certification Authority 2, O=America Online Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1
  Valid from Tue May 28 02:00:00 EDT 2002 until Tue Sep 29 10:08:00 EDT 2037

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=LuxTrust Global Root, O=LuxTrust s.a., C=LU
  Issuer:  CN=LuxTrust Global Root, O=LuxTrust s.a., C=LU
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xbb8
  Valid from Thu Mar 17 05:51:37 EDT 2011 until Wed Mar 17 05:51:37 EDT 2021

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority - G3, OU=(c) 2008 GeoTrust Inc. - For authorized use only, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority - G3, OU=(c) 2008 GeoTrust Inc. - For authorized use only, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x15ac6e9419b2794b41f627a9c3180f1f
  Valid from Tue Apr 01 20:00:00 EDT 2008 until Tue Dec 01 18:59:59 EST 2037

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Chambers of Commerce Root - 2008, O=AC Camerfirma S.A., SERIALNUMBER=A82743287, L=Madrid (see current address at www.camerfirma.com/address), C=EU
  Issuer:  CN=Chambers of Commerce Root - 2008, O=AC Camerfirma S.A., SERIALNUMBER=A82743287, L=Madrid (see current address at www.camerfirma.com/address), C=EU
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xa3da427ea4b1aeda
  Valid from Fri Aug 01 08:29:50 EDT 2008 until Sat Jul 31 08:29:50 EDT 2038

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=SwissSign Silver CA - G2, O=SwissSign AG, C=CH
  Issuer:  CN=SwissSign Silver CA - G2, O=SwissSign AG, C=CH
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x4f1bd42f54bb2f4b
  Valid from Wed Oct 25 04:32:46 EDT 2006 until Sat Oct 25 04:32:46 EDT 2036

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - G2, OU="(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - G2, OU="(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x4a538c28
  Valid from Tue Jul 07 13:25:54 EDT 2009 until Sat Dec 07 12:55:54 EST 2030

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert Assured ID Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Assured ID Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xce7e0e517d846fe8fe560fc1bf03039
  Valid from Thu Nov 09 19:00:00 EST 2006 until Sun Nov 09 19:00:00 EST 2031

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority, O="The Go Daddy Group, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority, O="The Go Daddy Group, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x0
  Valid from Tue Jun 29 13:06:20 EDT 2004 until Thu Jun 29 13:06:20 EDT 2034

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=AddTrust External CA Root, OU=AddTrust External TTP Network, O=AddTrust AB, C=SE
  Issuer:  CN=AddTrust External CA Root, OU=AddTrust External TTP Network, O=AddTrust AB, C=SE
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1
  Valid from Tue May 30 06:48:38 EDT 2000 until Sat May 30 06:48:38 EDT 2020

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=T-TeleSec GlobalRoot Class 3, OU=T-Systems Trust Center, O=T-Systems Enterprise Services GmbH, C=DE
  Issuer:  CN=T-TeleSec GlobalRoot Class 3, OU=T-Systems Trust Center, O=T-Systems Enterprise Services GmbH, C=DE
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1
  Valid from Wed Oct 01 06:29:56 EDT 2008 until Sat Oct 01 19:59:59 EDT 2033

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert Global Root G3, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Global Root G3, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: EC; Serial number: 0x55556bcf25ea43535c3a40fd5ab4572
  Valid from Thu Aug 01 08:00:00 EDT 2013 until Fri Jan 15 07:00:00 EST 2038

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=UTN-USERFirst-Client Authentication and Email, OU=http://www.usertrust.com, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Salt Lake City, ST=UT, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=UTN-USERFirst-Client Authentication and Email, OU=http://www.usertrust.com, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Salt Lake City, ST=UT, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x44be0c8b500024b411d336252567c989
  Valid from Fri Jul 09 13:28:50 EDT 1999 until Tue Jul 09 13:36:58 EDT 2019

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Class 2 Primary CA, O=Certplus, C=FR
  Issuer:  CN=Class 2 Primary CA, O=Certplus, C=FR
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x85bd4bf3d8dae369f694d75fc3a54423
  Valid from Wed Jul 07 13:05:00 EDT 1999 until Sat Jul 06 19:59:59 EDT 2019

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GeoTrust Global CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=GeoTrust Global CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x23456
  Valid from Tue May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2002 until Sat May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2022

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=SwissSign Platinum CA - G2, O=SwissSign AG, C=CH
  Issuer:  CN=SwissSign Platinum CA - G2, O=SwissSign AG, C=CH
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x4eb200670c035d4f
  Valid from Wed Oct 25 04:36:00 EDT 2006 until Sat Oct 25 04:36:00 EDT 2036

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign ECC Root CA - R5
  Issuer:  CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign ECC Root CA - R5
  Algorithm: EC; Serial number: 0x605949e0262ebb55f90a778a71f94ad86c
  Valid from Mon Nov 12 19:00:00 EST 2012 until Mon Jan 18 22:14:07 EST 2038

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=VeriSign Class 2 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3, OU="(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  CN=VeriSign Class 2 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3, OU="(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x6170cb498c5f984529e7b0a6d9505b7a
  Valid from Thu Sep 30 20:00:00 EDT 1999 until Wed Jul 16 19:59:59 EDT 2036

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Starfield Root Certificate Authority - G2, O="Starfield Technologies, Inc.", L=Scottsdale, ST=Arizona, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=Starfield Root Certificate Authority - G2, O="Starfield Technologies, Inc.", L=Scottsdale, ST=Arizona, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x0
  Valid from Mon Aug 31 20:00:00 EDT 2009 until Thu Dec 31 18:59:59 EST 2037

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=IdenTrust Public Sector Root CA 1, O=IdenTrust, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=IdenTrust Public Sector Root CA 1, O=IdenTrust, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xa0142800000014523cf467c00000002
  Valid from Thu Jan 16 12:53:32 EST 2014 until Mon Jan 16 12:53:32 EST 2034

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=D-TRUST Root Class 3 CA 2 EV 2009, O=D-Trust GmbH, C=DE
  Issuer:  CN=D-TRUST Root Class 3 CA 2 EV 2009, O=D-Trust GmbH, C=DE
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x983f4
  Valid from Thu Nov 05 03:50:46 EST 2009 until Mon Nov 05 03:50:46 EST 2029

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert Assured ID Root G3, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Assured ID Root G3, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: EC; Serial number: 0xba15afa1ddfa0b54944afcd24a06cec
  Valid from Thu Aug 01 08:00:00 EDT 2013 until Fri Jan 15 07:00:00 EST 2038

**adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=wwwcie.ups.com, OU=UPS-J2EE, O=United Parcel Service, L=Mahwah, ST=New Jersey, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x704087b50cd6823c2f560f9e746528fd
  Valid from Thu Mar 05 19:00:00 EST 2015 until Tue Mar 06 18:59:59 EST 2018**

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert Global Root G2, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Global Root G2, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x33af1e6a711a9a0bb2864b11d09fae5
  Valid from Thu Aug 01 08:00:00 EDT 2013 until Fri Jan 15 07:00:00 EST 2038

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
```

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145431/https-using-jersey-client to SSLContext for jersey ClientBuilder.

Comment: @JaydeepRajput I don't have issues building a working client for other services so this link is irrelevant to my issue.

Comment: Try enabling ssl logs Simply append '-Djavax.net.debug=ssl' in jvm args

Comment: @JaydeepRajput I've enabled ssl logs and added the result to the original question. I'll now examine them.