# Jersey-Server: handle HTTPS requests

Tags: java, jersey

I have been looking for documentation/instructions for how to make Jersey server accept HTTPS requests, and could not find anything helpful so far.

I am not sure where I should start at.

Does Jersey have a built-in support for HTTPS ? Is it enough if I just use `https` in the base URI?:

```
HttpServerFactory.create("https://localhost:1234");
```

Or should I also implement other things to support it?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145431/https-using-jersey-client

Comment: @canillas the thread in your link refers to Jersey Client and not to Jersey Server. Thank you anyway

Comment: sorry for my mistake, a bad read.

Comment: https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/https-clientserver-grizzly