# Connect to TLSv1.2 enabled server (https://10.15.15.3:index.jsp) using WebTarget

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

1. I have enabled TLSv1.2 in my server (View site information says 'Not Secure with red caution icon')
2. And I'm using the following code to connect from Java class

   ```
   Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
   WebTarget authTarget = client.target(restResource).path(path);
   Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = authTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
   Response response = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(null,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));
   ```

I receive the following exception.

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

What am I missing here, I'm new to https connection.

Comment: what client are you using? If it's the default one you have to set in your `ClientBuiler` all the ssl related things (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.html)

Comment: I'm using javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder; Please mention what are the ssl related things I should add.

Comment: use the java docs and check this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145431/https-using-jersey-client