# How to Consume a REST API with HTTPS?

Tags: java, rest, mule

I want to consume a rest api with HTTPS protocol, a certificate with .p12 is shared with me , I am stuck I don't know how to consume them can any one help me with this please, If i try to call the end point url's an error is throw stating no valid certificate is found.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are many tutorials online for how to fix that error.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429810/consuming-restful-service-over-https-with-certficate-using-java

Comment: Hi @Adam  I tried many solutions but using mule ESB I am not able to consume.Can you please help me with this

Comment: Hi I tried generating java key store, Now when i Use this JKS file in mule it is saying no trusted certificared, Do i need to generated any more files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the below code would help!! note the "insecure" attribute being set to "true", which would resolve the certificate trust issue. Hope it helps!!
`<tls:trust-store **insecure="true"** path="keystore.jks" type="jks" password="testing"/>`

Answer (score 1):

use spring security provider connector in mule and configure it.Please follow the following sample code.

and configure http inbound listener with jks file.